# Match strings whose length is isolated prime

Tags: regular-expression, programming-puzzle

Isolated prime definition from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Isolated_prime):

> An isolated prime is a prime number p such that neither p − 2 nor p + 2 is prime. In other words, p is not part of a twin prime pair. For example, 23 is an isolated prime since 21 and 25 are both composite.

Consider strings which consists of character `x` repeated n times, where n ≥ 0. You shall write a regex which matches strings whose length is an isolated prime, and rejects strings whose length is not an isolated prime.

Same rule as my previous question [Match strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19262/match-strings-whose-length-is-a-fourth-power):

- Any (ir)regular expression syntax is allowed, except for arbitrary code execution (to Perl users).
- Your solution should logically<sup>1</sup> work correctly for large number. This means that an answer that lists out all the lengths within certain range is disqualified.
- Please also include a short explanation about your approach to the problem (something like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19413/6638)).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some engine implements `*` with an upper limit. This question assumes that `*` doesn't have an upper limit (and the only limit is the length of the input string).</sub>

This question on SO might be useful as a starting point. [How to determine if a number is a prime with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex)

**Do you know?**

If you can solve this problem, with trivial modification, you can check whether a number is part of a [twin prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), since isolated prime has opposite definition of a twin prime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Perl, 54

```
/^(?!(..+)\1+$)(?=..(?:|(..+)\2+)$)(?=(..(.*))\4\3*$)/
```

I think this is not possible without the Perl look-ahead expression... Firstly, there is no positive regex to match the prime number. You can only match a non-prime by simulating multiplication: `(..+)\1+`. To negate it, I use negative look-ahead: `/^(?!(..+)\1+$)/` matches prime numbers (neglecting the 0, 1 case).

The beauty of the look-ahead is that it is zero-width, i.e. eats no characters. This means you can actually AND those conditions! My regex is composed of 3 look-aheads, corresponding to AND-ing 3 conditions:

- `(?!(..+)\1+$)` - N (length of the string) is the prime number
- `(?=..(?:|(..+)\2+)$)` - N-2 is a non-prime - this is a trival modification of the basic non-prime expression - `(..+)\1+`) - just add two characters. The `(?:|...)` is included to also match an empty string (case N=2 should match too).
- `(?=(..(.*))\4\3*$)` - N+2 is a non-prime - again, trivial modification of the basic non-prime expression - cut two characters out of one repetition.

Test:

```
$ perl -E'($"x$_)=~/^(?!(..+)\1+$)(?=..(?:|(..+)\2+)$)(?=(..(.*))\4\3*$)/&&say for(2..200)'
2
23
37
47
53
67
79
83
89
97
113
127
131
157
163
167
173
```

Comment: Instant accept. Don't think there is any other answer. I kinda expect this to be easy. My solution is the same, except that I also test for 1 in p-2 (you only test for composite and 0), but it doesn't affect the final result.

Comment: Well, easy... it seemed pretty impossible, until I got the idea to use look-aheads ;-)