# Golf the Lucas Lehmer Primality Test

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

your task is to write a program that uses the Lucas-Lehmer primality test to check whether an input number is prime or not. This prime number candidate has the form `2p-1` with p being prime. (Mersenne prime number)

### The Lucas-Lehmer-test

The n-th Mersenne number is prime if it is a divisor of the (n-1)-th Lucas-Lehmer number (LLN).
You can calculate the LLN, similiar to the Fibonacci numbers, based on a recursive algorithm:

```
L<n> = (L<n-1>)^2 - 2
```

The LLN for 2 is 14. So, for p=3, LLN<3-1>=14

### Evaluation

- You have to submit a function that takes p as input (Remember: `2^p-1`)
- The shortest solution will win.
- Your solution has to use the Lucas-Lehmer test
- The code must be executable.
- Output: boolean value or 1=prime/0=not prime

### Tests:

```
p --> 2^p-1  --> LLN<n-1> --> ?
3 --> 7      --> 14  --> prime
5 --> 31     --> 37634 > prime (1214*31)
```

Good Luck

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104768/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor, No, I request the LLT. The other one just any possible test.

Comment: I linked to an answer which implements the LLT. Besides, what does "*related*" mean if a question which asks for a specific test of a property is not related to a question which asks for any test of the same property?

Comment: O.k. but maybe there are other (shorter) solutions, e.g. in other languages.
Only because someone somewhere posted something this is not a duplicate. 

Of course it is related. But there are 48 search results on Mersenne and 467 on prime test. And only two especially on the LLT. And only one of them is a question.

And if I am expecting a special test, this is a different challenge. Of course there are matches within the possible answers. But as stated: there are a lot of prime test competitions with possible matching answers

Comment: He didn't say it was a duplicate, he said Related

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure this falls under `unobservable criteria`

Comment: @Mayube It does not. At least not in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
o<4IÍFnÍ}sÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/38bE83CvW97h3triw9P@/zcHAA)

**Explanation**

```
o<            # push 2^p-1
  4           # push 4
   IÍF        # p-2 times do:
      nÍ      # square and subtract 2
        }     # end loop
         sÖ   # LLN(n) % Mp == 0
```

If we didn't need boolean value output we could save a byte with `4IÍFnÍIo<%`  which returns **0** for prime and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
p=input()
s=4
exec's=(s*s-2)%(2**p-1);'*(p-2)
s>0>x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCoJAFIX39ykuQsw4IJTVxhg34cKFKeULhF1QKL3MTKRPPzmtWh3O38eL66cx9d30IB1FkWc9jPx2MgarD0AzdcJqaZVN0ngjU6U42cUnoSSvAdh8m89@/cGnH56ErXlTBojOLEEQAwAD/OfYDKND0VzLqhAQ2o7Y4eX@osKYyWT/q3NdNfWtbAvh93D8Ag)

Output is via exit code

Comment: Isn't this a snippet?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire it takes input in the first line and outputs by crashing / not crashing in the last line, which is meant by `Output is via exit code`. [This is a valid output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/64121).

Comment: Ok, it's a full program. I didn't read it as such, my bad! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>47 43</s> 41 bytes

Thanks @Kittsil for saving me 2 bytes!

```hs
f n=iterate(\v->mod(v^2-2)$2^n-1)4!!n-2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzazJLUosSRVI6ZM1y43P0WjLM5I10hTxSguT9dQ00RRMU/XyMbwf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqC8X8A)

Comment: Using pattern matching instead of guards saves you 4 bytes in this case
p 2=4;p n=p(x-1)^2-2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0fByNaEK0chzzZHI0/XUDPOSNeIK1ehwDY3P0UjR6FAU8MorgAobmtr8P8/AA)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica 44 Bytes

```
(s@3=14;s@n_:=Mod[s[n-1]^2-2,2^#-1];s@#==0)&
```

Test:

```
{#, %[#]} & /@ Prime[Range[2, 20]]
```

Too bad we can't use `MersennePrimeExponentQ` (22 bytes) since it doesn't appear to always use the LLT.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
l=lambda x:4*(x<3)or l(x-1)**2-2
f=lambda p:not l(p)%(2**p-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrRCgIhEAXQ9/2KYSGYEQ1We5LqD/YjjLIMU3EN7OttCLpwHy73lE975GTGiKfoXperg24PAvvRUK4QsauFhNBKT/4Pik258VVoh1qIwmJ4xiuEBNWl@w2NBL1wyU7ACR49rkS21JAabq3y2tfne2uoScKszrOEH4HxBQ)

I'd like to note that the Lucas-Lehmer test only applies to <s>odd primes</s> Mersenne numbers of the form 2<sup>*p*</sup>-1 where *p* is an odd prime. This program uses a recursive function for the Lucas-Lehmer numbers, and then a function that just tests if the *n*-th LLN is divisible by M<sub>*n*</sub>.

Comment: The Lucas Lehmer test only applies to Mersenne primes. And 2 is no Mersenne prime. So they have to apply to odd primes only.

Comment: @PaulStrobach Should have been more specific. The Lucas-Lehmer test only applies to Mersenne primes of the form 2^p-1 where p is an odd prime. I am aware that 2 is no Mersenne prime, but 2^2-1 is, which will not be detected by this test.

Comment: ok. misunderstood you: `L<2>=4, 4 % 3 != 0`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
for($s=4;++$i+1<$argn;)$s=($s**2-2)%(2**$argn-1);echo+!$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkrmT9Py2/SEOl2NbEWltbJVPb0AYsZa0JFAIKa2kZ6RppqmoYaWmBxXUNNa1TkzPytRVViq3//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 28 bytes

```
{0=(¯1+2*⍵)|(¯2+×⍨)⍣(⍵-2)⊢4}
```

Explanation:

```
                         ⊢4    ⍝ to the number 4,
                   ⍣(⍵-2)      ⍝ apply this function ⍵-2 times,
            (¯2+×⍨)            ⍝ N*N - 2
   (¯1+2*⍵)|                   ⍝ modulo 2^⍵ - 1
 0=                            ⍝ is the result 0?
```