# Find the nth Mersenne Prime

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

> A number is a Mersenne Prime if it is both prime and can be written in the form 2<sup>m</sup>-1, where m is a positive integer.

**For example:**

- 7 is a Mersenne Prime because it is 2<sup>3</sup>-1
- 11 is not a Mersenne Prime because it cannot be written as 2<sup>m</sup>-1
- 15 is not a Mersenne Prime because it is not prime

**The first few Mersenne primes:**

- 3
- 7
- 31
- 127
- 8191

**Your task:**

- Take a user input (it will be a positive integer) - let's call it n
- Find the n<sup>th</sup> Mersenne prime and output it in the format shown below

**Example output:**

With an input of `4`, the output should be `127`. (But this is [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) so any form of output is allowed)

---

I'll add my attempt at this as an answer, but I'm sure that it can be golfed down a bit.

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), all languages are accepted, and the shortest answer wins!

Comment: Please consider relaxing the output format. As it stands, the challenge consists of finding the prime (interesting part) and formatting the output (uninteresting)

Comment: @LuisMendo - done. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104508/58563)

Comment: @TheThonnu We often post "related" links in the comments of challenges; they're aren't accusations of being a duplicate, but are just there to help navigation between related questions.

Comment: Hey, nice question! As this stands, it would  be a perfect fit as a [tag:sequence] challenge. This allows the output format to be a bit more flexible, allowing the answers to focus more on the challenge, rather than the output format.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000668

Comment: @Seggan - thanks, added the tag.

Comment: @TheThonnu now with the tag, the I/O is looser. I suggest you read the [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) to familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: @Seggan - yeah, I saw it. I put the input/output there as an example, not as an exact template.

Comment: @TheThonnu then you should probably clarify in the post

Comment: @Seggan - done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 7 bytes

```
Þ∞E‹~æẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJHIiwiIiwiw57iiJ5F4oC5fsOm4bqOIiwiIiwiMSJd)

7 bytes flagless (change `Ẏ` to `i`) if 0-indexing is allowed.

### But how?

```
Þ∞E‹~æẎ
Þ∞      # all positive integers
  E‹    # as the power of 2 minus 1 (basically, all numbers that are of the form 2^m -  1)
    ~æ  # with only primes kept
      Ẏ # take the first (input) items
# The -G flag outputs the biggest of the final list
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th Mersenne prime, 1-indexed.

```javascript
n=>{for(k=1;n;n-=d<2)for(d=k-=~k;k%--d;);return k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEADvfcUeKmQpEerFw3b9gX9oaRLRlF1Jq5cQvx7b08DMvKbvtM7p@d6sqPM1cBW@5aDJRO5JSCy74YKHcBwt/yLFk7WOkJLfPkkglnpUAYaeQGBguO7sOoTcAMwqqy7@vOjDjHfTZim4r20ORrCMSE2pfw)

## `eval()` version, 48 bytes

*Suggested by [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

```javascript
n=>eval(`for(k=1;n;n-=d<2)for(d=k-=~k;k%--d;)k`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEDRfU4xixQcgoV008VkcoPeQYlaWmUsSclG7NVtsvrw@G@7221ZX5@vlux8C9yEZ7/bpEzIq4o8kpBodtMNT3AcNf8ixYvWjjAabCcLMIwEAhPD/egwIJQOYMmy5eSvKT@Veai@SMVj7UtQgtUgdbX9AQ)

#### How?

Numbers of the form \$2^n-1,\:n>1\$ can be computed recursively with:

$$\begin{cases} a(0)=3\\a(n)=2\times a(n-1)+1\end{cases}$$

Hence the golfed recurrence formula: `k-=~k`.

#### Commented

```javascript
n => {         // n = input
  for(         // outer loop:
    k = 1;     //   start with k = 1
    n;         //   stop when n = 0
               //   after each inner loop,
    n -= d < 2 //   decrement n if d = 1 (i.e. k is prime)
  )            //
    for(       //   inner loop:
      d =      //     update k to the next number of the form 2**N - 1
      k -= ~k; //     and initialize the divisor d to the same value
      k % --d; //     decrement d until it divides k
    );         //
  return k     // k is the n-th Mersenne prime: return it
}              //
```

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEDRfU4xixQcgoV008VkcoPeQYlaWmUsSclG7NVtsvrw@G@7221ZX5@vlux8C9yEZ7/bpEzIq4o8kpBodtMNT3AcNf8ixYvWjjAabCcLMIwEAhPD/egwIJQOYMmy5eSvKT@Veai@SMVj7UtQgtUgdbX9AQ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.lucas-lehmer`, 48 bytes

```factor
[ 1 lfrom [ lucas-lehmer ] lfilter lnth 2^ 1 - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCsIwEETv@Yr5gQYUT/UDxIsX8VRaCGFLg5u0bNZD/fm46MnLMLx5zByirtIe9@vt0uNJUojBqWr9pefw3pGDLt/wm6RMRl8x1I5pySTYhFR3W4ri7NzJtQEH8CxrxoA/dTScWK1xscvjZGKHscXADN8@)

0-indexed.

- `1 lfrom` A lazy list of the natural numbers
- `[ ... ] lfilter` Select the ones that...
- `lucas-lehmer` ...are Mersenne numbers
- `lnth` Take the nth one
- `2^ 1 -` Turn a Mersenne number into a Mersenne prime

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n=1,p=1:k and f(k-(p%n>n&n+1),n+1,p*n*n)or~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDkAwFAXQ3Ve8hbQ8QyUWSf1LhSLl9qWxWPx6sZztyH1tEV3O3h7unGZHgWENizVDIIeZvAqtkhIjKjRG8wdLjRo6pqdF9jFRoB2UHNZFGe71UJCkHdd/dX4B)

Uses the [Wilson's Theorem prime generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260), which could be implemented like this to find the `k`'th prime:

```python
f=lambda k,n=1,p=1:k and f(k-p%n,n+1,p*n*n)or~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxCoAgGAbQvVP8S6Bmgw4NgocxzBLrU8SlpatbrQ9euduRoXsP9nTX6h0lCatkscokcvAUWJrLCInpUwEBnuszo4dcKVEEVYd9Y0rqhZuBSo1of@L9BQ)

But, modifies it to count only numbers of the form \$2^a-1\$ which are tested for as `n&n+1==0`. This is combined with the primality check as `p%n>n&n+1`.

Because this method recurses through all potential primes whether or not they have form \$2^a-1\$, it already exceeds the default maximum recursion depth for inputs of 5 and above.

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes**

```python
f=lambda k,n=3:k and f(k-all(n%d for d in range(2,n)),n-~n)or n/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxCoAwEAR7X3GNkIOIGLEJ@JiTGJXEjQQbG78etbIbmGGO61wTTCl@jLJPTihojL0NJHDkVWgkRoX65ZTJ0QbKgmVWRoNZo7nBr0BryheEP@j0wLaiI284vxGXBw)

Recurses through numbers of the \$2^a-1\$ by repeatedly applying `n->2*n+1`, using trial division to test for primality.

Comment: Now that OP has added the [tag:sequence] tag, you can output infinitely for 45: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsIwEEbhfU8xIpUkLUKwq5bxIlLKX6wkEJOhBqSnj5Ltx@PJkV2Kt3KmFMNBsvuYKbuNXn7/ZBqaKhzwXp8w6Bd@VJnNMC5XSaK0MtAFLGybr/NhIztKizsu6OyJa62gJzH8H0zo2JbyAw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes

```python
a=1
while 1:a-=~a;0in(a%d for d in range(2,a))or print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwFAX3nuKBCElpxYqCVnIDbyBSvja1gZqE9It040XcdKHeqbdRWlfvMQzz_PiWK2e7fu-Dsaxqup4KiijO1WEgx2id5XPvvJAiIglMEXTDwZwZ7OBs3WIQwZVGaULDWL9vXCabfksqndwrU2ukGSXqQbuFsYJmBUoXUMBYBLIXLZYxSflDQ0mQHAOvUqz-t-vG_QI)

`a-=~a` taken from [Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251596)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>63</s></sup> 51 bytes

```c
d;k;f(n){for(k=1;n;n-=d<2)for(d=k-=~k;k%--d;);n=k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLboMwELznK1ZISHbAaoBGJHLcS9WvKByQbVLk1kQYqaiIfnrp8kjaWPJ6Pbsz3rFkZynHUXHDS2JpX9YNMSLillsm1CmmE6CEYeLbcOMzpjjlVhg@jJVt4aOoLKHQbwDXBOjuomWr1WsOAvokhDSEJAohijE5RMcpTaJdiuc@fowP6cBnrqyta0G@Fc0Wo5ZGN4uEl3UvcdYdn3HvvRD@3xNvZeOQQKbnK6t0h7QdX9MTuOpL1yW5DkYfVmB7QzgEwdxNZ7HFzNVQi2qLVAARvys5LJWkpfeoRvT2CzMz/2u4NNhSEs9XwJ4Ao@8yi67aEFx4M@6E0PkqO2yG8UeW78XZjezzFw)

*A port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251596/9481).*
*Saved a whopping 13 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!!!*

Inputs positive integer \$n\$.
Returns the 1-based \$n^{\text{th}}\$ Mersenne prime.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVDRboMwDHzvV1hISElLtAKraOVmL9O@YuUBJaFD2UJFkIZWsU8fM5R2a6Q4ztl38UWJo1LD0KBGiyVz/FzWDbMyRodOSL1P@AhoaYX8tmhDITRydNJiP1SuhY@icozDeQG0RsB0J6Nao19zkHBOI8giSOMI4oSSbbwb0zReZ3Ruksdkm/U4cVXtfAvqrWiWFI2yprlIBIfuJTl0u2famyCC//c0mNk0JLDx@cpp0xFtjXO6B199mbpk18H4wwwsbwjCajV180nsYuZqqCW1i9QKYrwreSqVrOX3qCH09gsTM/9rODXUUrIg1CCegGLoD45ctRH46GbcS2nyWbZf9MOPKt@Lox/E5y8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online") by doing the same thing as Arnauld's JS answer (sorry lol)

Comment: @Steffan Arnauld's wizardry tops my feeble efforts yet again! lol Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 85 bytes

```
Y+X:-X mod Y<1->Y<X;Y+1+X.
Q-N-R:-2+Q,Q- \Q-N-R;N>1,Q- \Q-(N-1)-R;R is Q.
W-R:-3-W-R.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo7CoAwEAV7T7GlEl8gahXFIwRi4wYsBQmoERU8fvxgNcww2x7mMOG4fIxOsAbTEkZyjULrGq6dUIJlYmHQaRTC5hY0fFqbVv2WGqjsKR35g6xM@ncu8UBGDarAOW27X8@UMxlv)

-4 bytes thanks to Jo King

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
&‘<Ẓø#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//JuKAmDzhupLDuCPhuar///80)

```
     #     Count up the first n matches
      Ṫ    then take the last
    ø      starting from 0:
&          Is the candidate bitwise AND
 ‘         itself + 1
  <        less than
   Ẓ       whether or not it's prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>116 99 88</s></sup> 85 bytes

```python
def f(n,i=1,j=0):
 while j!=n:i+=1;m=2**i-1;j+=all(m%k for k in range(2,m))
 print(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbBCoMwDADQu1@RHQaJdrC6nZR8jLB2praxlIr49R17p5evuu76au3jPHhUI2xN4CdNHZyrRAfhxjrJwHZOPPa9POwcBl5ixHTfwO8FNhCFsujX4WgSUQe5iFZM1Dz@I5qPikTU3j8)

- (-24 thanks to Jo King)
- (-4 thanks to pxeger)

## [Python+](https://github.com/nayakrujul/python-plus), <sup><strike>78</strike></sup> 73 bytes

```python
n=int(§())
i=1
j=0
€j!=n
 i+=1;m=2**i-1;j+=all(m%k£k:range(2,m))
$(m)
```

- (-1 thanks to pxeger)
- (-4 thanks to Jo King)

Comment: You can combine the `i+=1` `j+=all((2**i-1)%k for k in range(2,2**i-1))` lines into one, saving 3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw9CoAwDEDhvaeIg5BaBatOSg7j4E9qiaVUxNNXBMfHBy88aT@lz1mIJSFLuBJqrZisctSqe2e/gCtIRjZkJ2do9h6xqypurC4PWM8IB7BAnGVbsKt/0irEb/lnzsML "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: also, assigning `2**i-1` to a variable would save six bytes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, updated

Comment: the python+ code is 73 bytes in UTF-8. does it have a custom codepage? I can't find it

Comment: @Steffan - thanks for noticing. I accidentally wrote the number of characters.

Comment: It is forbidden to [add features to a pre-existing language, after the challenge was posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12714/80214): ([commit from 1hr ago](https://github.com/nayakrujul/numlang-9ee9/commit/f202bc53bb7de23e153f3dda9462d09e8bb82ed4))

Comment: It is also encouraged to post a separate answer instead of editing an existing one. CGCC is ok with multiple answers in unique languages.

Comment: @Razetime, I rolled back the edit. There is no mention of Numlang now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
2^MersennePrimeExponent@#-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yjON7WoODUvLzWgKDM31bWiID8vNa/EQVnXUO0/UCivRMEhPdok9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
!fṗm←İ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHt4c7puY/aJhzZYPT//39TAA)

```
!fṗm←İ2
   m    # map over
     İ2 # powers of 2
    ←   # decrementing each one
 f      # then filter to keep only
  ṗ     # primes
!       # and get the input-th one.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
;2{;X≜^-₁ṗ}ᶠ⁽t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz/ihrDigoLhuol94bWQ/zsyeztY4omcXi3igoHhuZd94bag4oG9dP//WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5XQ)

Worth noting it started with `∧{≜;2↔^-₁ṗ}ᶠ↖?t`.

```
;2{       }ᶠ⁽     Find the first n possible outputs given 2 from:
   ;X             pair the 2 with an unbound variable,
     ≜            label the variable to an integer,
      ^           raise the 2 to that power,
       -₁         subtract 1,
         ṗ        and fail if not prime.
             t    Yield only the last of the results.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞o<ʒp
```

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8fJtTkwr@/wcA)

Outputting the 1-based \$n^{th}\$ value like the example in the challenge description, would be **8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** in the [legacy version of 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) instead:

```
µNbSPNp*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/pOAAvwKt//9NAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞      # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 o     # Take 2 to the power each: [2,4,8,...
  <    # Decrease each by 1: [1,3,7,...]
   ʒ   # Filter this list by:
    p  #  Only keep the prime numbers
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

µ      # Continue looping while `¾` is not equal to the (implicit) input-integer:
       # (counter variable `¾` is 0 by default)
 N     #  Push the loop-index
  b    #  Convert it to a binary string
   S   #  Convert it to a list of digits
    P  #  Check if all bits are 1 by taking the product
 N     #  Push the loop-index again
  p    #  Check whether it's a prime number
     * #  Check if both are truthy
       #  (if they are: implicitly increase `¾` by 1)
       # (after which the last index `N` is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 38 bytes

```
\d+
_
$
_$`
"$+"}/^(__+)\1+$/+`$
_$`
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyZFmyueS4UrXiWBS0lFW6lWP04jPl5bM8ZQW0VfOwEiEf//vykA) No test suite due to the program's use of history. Explanation:

```
\d+
_
```

On the first pass through the loop, replace the input with `1` in unary.

```
$
_$`
```

Double and increment the value.

```
/^(__+)\1+$/+`
```

While the value is composite...

```
$
_$`
```

... double and increment the value.

```
"$+"}
```

Repeat the above `n` times.

```
_
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹ηＷθ«≔⊕⊗ηη≧⁻﹪±Π…¹ηηθ»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU67DoMgFJ31KxiviR06dHJq2sVBY/wDxBsgQVC4tEPTb6cYOp2cnKdQ3AvHTUq93SONcVvQw9F09T0ELS1cW6YyeyttkGWBferqL/VWeNzQEq7wdHExGVXTlEA18L34Zi0VwaBtDC0b3BqNgxElJ4TJZyoIZm4llqmSb9l54VtPXluCBw90Nncp3dLlZX4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start with `1`.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until `n=0`.

```
≔⊕⊗ηη
```

Double and increment the value.

```
≧⁻﹪±Π…¹ηηθ
```

If the value is prime then decrement `n`. For decremented powers of 2, `(n-1)!%-n` is either `0` for composite or `-1` for prime. (In fact, `(n-1)!²%n` is `0` for any positive non-prime and `1` for any prime.)

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the final value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```ruby
->n{r=1;1until(2...r+=r+1).all?{|x|r%x>0}&&1>n-=1;r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vusjW0NqwNK8kM0fDSE9Pr0jbtkjbUFMvMSfHvrqmoqZItcLOoFZNzdAuTxeosqj2f4FCWrRR7H8A)

Comment: `r+=r+1` can be `r-=~r` for -1

Comment: `{|x|r%x>0} `=>`{r%_1>0}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èõ!²mÉ øX*j}iU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yPUhsm3JIPhYKmp9aVU&input=NA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$8\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 6.585 bytes

```
F@p{^2mC
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJGQHB7XjJtQyIsIiJd)

Outputs an infinite list of Mersenne primes.

```
F@p{^2mC
      mC # Infinite list of counting numbers
    ^2   # 2^x
   {     # Decrement
F@       # Filter for...
  p      # Primality
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain how you got to that bytecount? I'm assuming this means there are 96 characters in Fig. Is there a page that lists the characters (like in other languages like 05AB1E)?

Comment: @TheThonnu yes, Fig uses all the printable ASCII characters (barring the tab) for its codepage. If you were wondering how I got an irrational byte count, well, its allowed by site rules now.

Comment: Yes, I know it's allowed. I was just wondering where the codepage was. Thanks for clarifying.