# Am I a Cullen Number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

A Cullen Number is any number that is contained in the sequence generated using the formula:

C(n) = (n*2^n)+1.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that receives an input and outputs a truthy/falsy value based on whether the input is a Cullen Number.

### Input:

A non-negative integer between 0 and 10^9 (inclusive).

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value that indicates whether the input is a Cullen Number.

### Test Cases:

```
Input:    Output:
1   --->  truthy
3   --->  truthy
5   --->  falsy
9   --->  truthy
12  --->  falsy
25  --->  truthy
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: What's the range of *n*? In particular, is 1 a Cullen Number?

Comment: @ais523 according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002064), it is. `n` seems to be 0-based.

Comment: Fair enough. Just needed to know whether my Jelly answer should have an `Ḷ` or `R` in it :-)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89436/31716)

Comment: Umm, what's with the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **Pyth, <s>6</s> 5 bytes**

```
/mh.<
```

[try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Fmh.<&input=25&debug=0)

Answer (score 18):

### x86_64 machine code ([System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)), <strike>28</strike> 27 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Cody Gray, thanks!

A constant-time algorithm!

```
_cullen:
   0:   0f bd cf    bsrl    %edi, %ecx
   3:   0f bd c1    bsrl    %ecx, %eax
   6:   89 ca       movl    %ecx, %edx
   8:   29 c2       subl    %eax, %edx
   a:   0f bd c2    bsrl    %edx, %eax
   d:   29 c1       subl    %eax, %ecx
   f:   d3 e1       shll    %cl, %ecx
  11:   ff c1       incl    %ecx
  13:   31 c0       xorl    %eax, %eax
  15:   39 f9       cmpl    %edi, %ecx
  17:   0f 94 c0    sete    %al
  1a:   c3          retq
```

**Explanation:**

Let *y* an integer and `x=y*2^y + 1`.
Taking logs, we have `y + log2(y) = log2(x-1)`, thus `y=log2(x-1)-log2(y)`. Plugging back the value of y, we get `y=log2(x-1)-log2(log2(x-1)-log2(y))`. Doing this one more time, we obtain: `y=log2(x-1)-log2[log2(x-1)-log2(log2(x-1)-log2(log2(x-1)-log2(y)))]`.

Let us remove the last terms (of the order of `log2(log2(log2(log2(x))))`, this should be safe!), and assume that `x-1≈x`, we obtain:
`y≈log2(x)-log2[log2(x)-log2(log2(x))]`

Now, letting `f(n) = floor(log2(n))`, it can be verified manually that `y` can be exactly retrieved by:
`y=f(x)-f[f(x)-f(f(x))]`,
for *y < 26*, and thus *x ⩽ 10^9*, as specified by the challenge<sup>(1)</sup>.

The algorithm then simply consists of computing *y* given *x*, and verify that *x == y*2^y + 1*.
The trick is that `f(n)` can simply be implemented as the `bsr` instruction (bit-scan reverse), which returns the index of the first 1-bit in *n*, and `y*2^y` as `y << y`.

**Detailed code:**

```
_cullen:                                 ; int cullen(int x) {
   0:   0f bd cf    bsrl    %edi, %ecx   ;  int fx = f(x);
   3:   0f bd c1    bsrl    %ecx, %eax   ;  int ffx = f(f(x));
   6:   89 ca       movl    %ecx, %edx   
   8:   29 c2       subl    %eax, %edx   ;  int a = fx - ffx;
   a:   0f bd c2    bsrl    %edx, %eax   ;  int ffxffx = f(a);
   d:   29 c1       subl    %eax, %ecx   ;  int y = fx - ffxffx;
   f:   d3 e1       shll    %cl, %ecx    ;  int x_ = y<<y;
  11:   ff c1       incl    %ecx         ;  x_++;
  13:   31 c0       xorl    %eax, %eax
  15:   39 f9       cmpl    %edi, %ecx
  17:   0f 94 c0    sete    %al
  1a:   c3          retq                 ;  return (x_ == x);
                                         ; }
```

<sup>(1)</sup>In fact, this equality seems to hold for values of *y* up to 50000.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure this qualifies as the most interesting code for this challenge so far.  +1

Comment: Pre-XORing `eax` would allow you to eliminate the `movzbl`, saving 1 byte. You'd need to do the XOR before the `cmpl` so it doesn't clobber the flags, of course, but that's totally fine because nothing after that depends on `eax`. Or, you could just decide that the method returns a Boolean in only the lower 8 bits, saving all 3 bytes!

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
Ḷæ«`i’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2Hlx1anZD5qGHm////jUwB)

Takes input as a command-line argument. If given a Cullen number C(*n*), outputs *n*+1 (which is truthy in Jelly, being an nonzero integer; note that we have *n*≥0 because the input is an integer, and Cullen numbers with negative *n* are never integers). If given a non-Cullen number, returns 0, which is falsey in Jelly.

### Explanation

```
Ḷæ«`i’
Ḷ        Form a range from 0 to (the input minus 1)
 æ«      Left-shift each element in the range by 
   `       itself
    i’   Look for (the input minus 1) in the resulting array
```

Basically, form an array of Cullen numbers minus one, then look for the input minus one in it. If the input is a Cullen number, we'll find it, otherwise we won't. Note that the array is necessarily long enough to reach to the input, because C(*n*) is always greater than *n*.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Neil*

```js
f=(n,k,x=k<<k^1)=>x<n?f(n,-~k):x==n
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k,x=k<<k^1)=>x<n?f(n,-~k):x==n

console.log(JSON.stringify([...Array(1000).keys()].filter(n => f(n))))
```

Comment: Does `x<n?f(n,k+1):x==n` work?

Comment: @Neil It sure does. :-)

Comment: Why does `~k work, while k+1 overloads the callstack?

Comment: @trlkly Basically, `undefined+1===NaN` but `-~undefined===1`. You can [read more about this here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105982/58563).

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 28 bytes

```
f n=or[x*2^x+1==n|x<-[0..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza/KLpCyyiuQtvQ1javpsJGN9pATy8vNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQppCtLGOpY6hkY6Raex/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 46 bytes

```r
pryr::f(x%in%lapply(0:x,function(y)(y*2^y+1)))
```

Anonymous function. Checks if `x` is generated in the sequence C(n) for n in [0,x].

3 bytes golfed by Giuseppe.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM6Ma9So8LWNiexoCCnUsPQqkIHLlupqVGpZRRXqW2oqalZy5WmYawJJAyNQKSRKZhtYGRiCGMYaf7//x8A)

Comment: use `x%in%...` instead of `any(x==...)`; that'll drop you 4 bytes

Comment: So if I golf this by changing the `lapply` to simply checking the vector, and use `scan` instead of taking function arguments - I get @giuseppe 's answer. Thanks for posting it separately so I can see what I'm missing - I learn more by trying something on my own, even though I usually lose.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 8 bytes

```
@Dº*≥Dlε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fweXQLq1HnUtdcs5t/f/fyBQA)

```
           Implicit input
@          Range [1,...,Input]
 D         Duplicate
  º        2^n each element
   *       Multiply those two array
    ≥      Increment everything (now I have an array of all Cullen Numbers)
     Dl    Push array length (= get input again, can't get again implicitly or using a function because it would be a string so I'd waste a byte again)
       ε   Is input in array?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes

```php
for(;$argn>$c=1+2**$n*$n++;);echo$argn==$c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaGaoZP0/Lb9IwxosYqeSbGuobaSlpZIHRNra1prWqckZ@RDVtirJ1v//AwA)

Comment: Is `$argn` a special variable? Changing it to `$a` would save 6 bytes: https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSaKtkaGaoZP0/Lb9Iw1ol0U4l2dZQ20hLSyUPiLS1rTWtU5Mz8oHqbFWSrf//BwA

Comment: @topher Yes  `$argn` is available if you run PHP from the command line with the `-R` option

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
ÝDo*¹<å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8FyXfK1DO20OL/3/39AIAA)

**Explanation:**

```
ÝDo*¹<å Example input: 9. Stack: [9]
Ý       Range 0-input. Stack: [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
 D      Duplicate. Stack: [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
  o     2** each item in the list. Stack: [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]]
   *    Multiply the two lists. Stack: [[0, 2, 8, 24, 64, 160, 384, 896, 2048, 4608]]
    ¹   Push input again. Stack: [[0, 2, 8, 24, 64, 160, 384, 896, 2048, 4608],9]
     <  Decrement. Stack: [[0, 2, 8, 24, 64, 160, 384, 896, 2048, 4608],8]
      å Is the first item of the stack in the second item? Stack: [1]
        Implicit print.
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, C++, Java, C#, D : 70 bytes

Due to the similarities between all these languages, this code works for each

```cpp
int c(int n){for(int i=0;i<30;++i)if((1<<i)*i+1==n)return 1;return 0;}
```

Comment: I'll post the optimized D version this time, some pretty D-specific tricks can be used.

Comment: Suggest `i=30;i--;)if(i<<i==n-1)` instead of `i=0;i<30;++i)if((1<<i)*i+1==n)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:i<<i!=n-1and f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcuxCsIwFIXhPU9x3CxewUQcDM3aJ3ATh2gTvFBvQ0zBPn0MCE6H/4OT1vKcxdQa3eRf99FDiN3Bct/zxsleexkRtw13uqtxzmCw4HoknAnaEMzpZhVSZilgUih5bd0@3LX5@SUvQSF8HiEV@9fBT@9Qvw)

Outputs by not crashing / crashing, as *currently* allowed by [this meta concensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/64121).

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
i=0
n=input()-1
while i<<i<n:i+=1
i<<i>n<c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETv@xVLTooIpuLBkHjToyd/oMSFLtRNWFNsvz6mIF6GN7xh8lKGJF2N6UnBGFM5HEACS57KZru38Bl4JGTv2YvjXbCw8kV8rG3@09YBFl1aIs0UcX1rnJWl4EOnVmiOlAve@xddVZO6v7/145vqEc5gO@hOXw)

Outputs via exit code

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 40 bytes

```
lambda n:any(x<<x==n-1for x in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAgGAbQq3yjgQ0mDUmepBqMysL6DXHQ01uuj/fmeHqSxUJjLrd51s2AlKHM0jgmrakVhw9IuAjBkN0ZNU2p5CpNkmPgEB1H1y8Kb7goMsdhmfvfBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
a=0:26;scan()%in%(1+a*2^a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9HWwMrIzLo4OTFPQ1M1M09Vw1A7UcsoLlHzv6GCsYKlgqGRgpHpfwA)

A slightly different approach than the [other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127079/67312); reads from `stdin` and since the input is guaranteed to be between 0 and 10^9, we just have to check `n` between 0 and 26.

Comment: I never remember `scan()`. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

To cover the case of *n* = 1, it requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems.

```apl
⊢∊1+⍳×2*⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/5OB5KOuRY86ugy1H/VuPjzdSAtI/f@ffGiFoYKxgqWCoZGCkSkA)

`⊢` [is] *n* (the argument)

`∊` a member of

`1` one

`+` plus

`⍳` the **i**ntegers 0 … (*n*-1)

`×` times

`2` two

`*` to the power of

`⍳` the **i**ntegers 0 … (*n*-1)

Comment: So, "default on many systems" means that it just *exists*?

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, it would be wrong to call `⎕IO←0` non-standard, as many indeed always have it set like that, with no specification necessary each time.

Comment: Well. I'm going to use that trick in MY for sure (and MY can have non-0 and non-1 Index Origins) if I ever get the chance to.

Comment: @Zacharý Wouldn't that require an actual install base/versions where those values are default? E.g. in SAX and ngn, `⎕IO←0`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would. And MY does have three iotas, so I think that wouldn't be used anyways.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
[n<<n|1for n in range(26)].count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPzrPxiavxjAtv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcPITDNWLzm/NK/kP5qMoYGBgaYVF2dmmkKaRh6IxVlQlJlXopD3HwA)

Creates the list of Cullen numbers up to `10^9`, then counts how many times the input appears in it. Thanks to Vincent for pointing out `n<<n|1` instead of `(n<<n)+1`, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: You can save two bytes using `n<<n|1` (`n<<n` being even) ;)

Comment: This fails for `838860801`. You need `range(26)`, because the range isn't inclusive.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks. I've done this for a while and still sometimes forget ranges are right-exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 17 bytes

```
max(Ans=seq(X2^X+1,X,0,25
```

**Explanation**

```
seq(X2^X+1,X,0,25 Generate a list of Cullen numbers in the range
Ans=              Compare the input to each element in the list, returning a list of 0 or 1
max(              Take the maximum of the list, which is 1 if any element matched
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation to this.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip.

Comment: That works, but a command-by-command explanation usually helps garner most upvotes.  I would reccomend doing something like the explanation on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136815/69331).  I don't know why somebody downvoted your post though.  It's usually common courtesy to leave a comment when you do so, although that idea is often ignored.

Comment: Your welcome.  I remember when I first joined the site, people told these types of things to me.  Just passing on the favour.

Answer (score 2):

## D, 65 bytes

This is a port of @HatsuPointerKun's algorithm to D (the original was already D code, but this is with D-specific tricks)

```d
T c(T)(T n){for(T i;i<30;++i)if((1<<i)*i+1==n)return 1;return 0;}
```

## How? (D specific tricks)

D's template system is shorter than C++'s, and can infer types. And D also initializes its variables to the default upon declaration.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5.5 bytes (11 nibbles)

```
?.`,$+~*^2
```

Returns 1-based index in list of Cullen numbers (truthy), or zero (falsy) if not a Cullen number.

```
?.`,$+~*^2      # full function
?.`,$+~*^2$$$   # (with implicit arguments shown):
 .              # map over
  `,$           # 0..input-1
                # with function:
     +          #   add
      ~         #   1 (default)
                #   to
        ^2      #   2 to the power of
          $     #   input
       *   $    #   multiplied by input
?           $   # and get the index of the input in this
                # (or zero if not found)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
~n=n∈0:n.|>x->x*2^x+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BasMwEEXX1ikGr@TWDrVLFg3I7TaXCCj1hE4REyGNQYGSdc6ZizhK3RSSWQ1/3vz/v0dHtk3TdGTD59PpZcWLnz41fXrqNum5nXb7AATEENAOjhijrhTksTVswUCUQH6ho3ckmmoom6bpy6pSBbEfJRPehoh6zVKDzTImj5@CQ75sjSkljPJ1KOEd8oawgp11EVWxH2V@P/76qMIHYnGs/2x7mIns@GFjxCBwezFwy1DIw9TmstdSAHOWen0Ulv/CNfyg3h6BtrsHuuU9cAE)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
MemberQ[(r=Range@#-1)2^r+1,#]&
```

Pure function taking a nonnegative integer as input and returning `True` or `False`. If the input is `n`, then `(r=Range@#-1)` sets the variable `r` to be `{0, 1, ..., n-1}`, and then `r2^r+1` vectorially computes the first `n` Cullen numbers. `MemberQ[...,#]` then checks whether `n` is an element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
!Table[x*2^x+1,{x,0,#}]~FreeQ~#&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 45 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and ouputs to the VBE immediate window

*Must be run in a clean module or have values for i,j be reset to default value of 0 between runs*

```vba
While j<[A1]:j=(i*2 ^ i)+1:i=i+1:Wend:?j=[A1]
```

#### Input / Output

I/O as seen in VBE immediate window

```vba
[A1]=25
While j<[A1]:j=(i*2 ^ i)+1:i=i+1:Wend:?j=[A1]
True

[A1]=1: i=0:j=0 ''# clearing module values
While j<[A1]:j=(i*2 ^ i)+1:i=i+1:Wend:?j=[A1]
True    

[A1]=5: i=0:j=0 ''# clearing module values
While j<[A1]:j=(i*2 ^ i)+1:i=i+1:Wend:?j=[A1]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swi-Prolog, 69 bytes

`f(X)` succeeds if it can find a value I where X = I*2^I+1. The range hint stops it running out of stack space, but it's enough for the range of Cullen numbers up to 10^9 in the question spec.

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
f(X):-I in 0..30,X#=I*2^I+1,label([I]).
```

e.g.

```
f(838860801).
true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 9 bytes

```
$0?1+$2^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XA3lBbxShO5f9/I1MA)

### Explanation

```
$0           n is 0-indexed
  ?          Mode query. Given input n, output true/false for if n is in the sequence.
   1+$2^$    Each item in the sequence equals `1+index*2^index`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[in?&map 0..25'n->1+n*2^n]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?hBfxpN)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-d`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÑpU ¶NÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWQ&code=0XBVILZOyQ&input=MjU)

```
ÑpU ¶NÉ     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
Ñ           :Multiply by 2
 pU         :Raised to the power of U
    ¶       :Is equal to
     N      :Array of all inputs
      É     :Minus 1
            :Implicit output of whether or not any U returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 30 bytes

```
{$_∈({1+$++*2**$++}...*>$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiX@UUeHRrWhtoq2tpaRlhaQqtXT09OyU4nXrP1fnFipoKQSr2Brp1CdpqASX6ukkJZfpGCop2dk@h8A)

The parenthesized expression is a list of generated Cullen numbers, taken up to the point where a number is greater than the input argument (`* > $_`).  Then we just check that the input argument is a member of that list (`∈`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ʀ:E*›c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyoA6RSrigLpjIiwiIiwiMVxuM1xuNVxuOVxuMTJcbjI1Il0=)

### Explained

```
ʀ:E*›c
ʀ:     # push 2 copies of the range [0, input]
  E    # 2 ** x for x in ^
   *   # vectorised multiply with the other copy
    ›  # + 1
     c # contains the input?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
RD2@z*s1-Aq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FquDXIwcqrSKDXUdCyEiUIkFi4xMISwA)

##### Explanation

```python
RD2@z*s1-Aq  # Implicit input
RD           # Push range(input) and duplicate
  2@         # Pop one copy and push 2 ** each
    z*       # Multiply elementwise
      s1-    # Push the input decremented
         Aq  # Is this in the list?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 8 bytes

```
Đ0⇹ŘĐ«⁺∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9weXT//8SQMOKHucWYxJDCq@KBuuKIiP//MQ)

```
Đ             implicit input; Đuplicate
 0⇹Ř          Řangify from 0 to n
    Đ         Đuplicate
     «        bitshift left
      ⁺       increment
       ∈      is input in list of Cullen numbers?; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 24 bytes

```
[0,:|~a*(2^a)+1=b|_Xq}?0
```

### Explanation

```
[0,:|           FOR a = 0 to b (input from cmd line)
~a*(2^a)+1=b    IF calculating this a results in b
|_Xq            THEN quit, printing 1
}               NEXT a
?0              We haven't quit early, so print 0 and end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 19 bytes

```
{&1=x-{x**/x#2}'!x}
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%7B%261%3Dx-%7Bx%2a%2a%2Fx%232%7D%27%21x%7D%271%203%209%2012%2025) Truthy is an array with a number in it: `,3` or `,0` et cetera. Falsey is an empty array: `()` or `!0` depending on your interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 56 bytes

```java
i->{int n,c;for(n=0;(c=n*(2<<n++-1)+1)<i;);return c==i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xasQwEETr@Cu2lOKziB1SBFlXpAikSHVlSKHoZCNHXgl5fXAc/nbHATtl8DS7zDyG6fRFFyFa7M7fs@tjSATd4omRnBfNiIZcQPG6PjKL45d3BozXwwDv2iHcMli0@gNpWs4luDP0S8pOlBy2H5@gUzvwFf7VVlm/IdnWpsNLCN5qPEIDCmZXHG8OCfBgZBMSQ/UgmVF4z6q6xjwvSp6XvHaSy2RpTAhGKSeneeuX2d3pOpDtRRhJxGUFeWSN0DH6Kys5l39T/uEed3LPO7my2glWTxs4ZdP8Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

```
n->!prod(i=0,n,n-i*2^i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDEDRq0SnRhKwBcf2KEJBKlnSELx/7PKHx7fuwq/FgAqh3Dbz@SSpJykpy1Fu4YwxpiddSyYoF4G56LdgB24rIykixg8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `-c`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖıỴ;Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NiVDNCVCMSVFMSVCQiVCNCUzQiVDNiU4NyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTI1JmZsYWdzPS1j)

Port of user62131's Jelly answer.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖDO×⁺Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NkRPJUMzJTk3JUUyJTgxJUJBJUM2JTg3JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MjUmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖıỴ;Ƈ  # Implicit input
       # Decrement the input
Ė      # Push [0..input-1]
  Ỵ    # Left bit-shift each
 ı ;   # number by itself
    Ƈ  # Is (input - 1)
       # in this list?
       # Implicit output
```

```python
ĖDO×⁺Ƈ  # Implicit input
Ė       # Push [0..input]
 D      # Duplicate it
  O     # Push 2 ** that
   ×    # Multiply together
    ⁺   # Increment each
     Ƈ  # Is the input
        # in this list?
        # Implicit output
```