# Count up diagonally!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

We have lots of horizontal axis for numbers, but I honestly think they're kind of boring. Your task today is to build me a portion of a diagonal axis between two distinct non-negative integers given as input.

### How to build a diagonal axis?

- Let's take an example, with the input `0, 5`. Our axis should look like this:

  ```
  0
   1
    2
     3
      4
       5
  ```
- However, our axis should look nice for numbers that have more digits too! If the input is, for instance `0, 14`, the new axis should be:

  ```
  0
   1
    2
     3
      4
       5
        6
         7
          8
           9
            10
              11
                12
                  13
                    14
  ```
- The idea is that the first digit of next number on the axis must always be placed exactly after the last digit of the previous number. To understand the idea even better, here is another example with `997, 1004`:

  ```
  997
     998
        999
           1000
               1001
                   1002
                       1003
                           1004
  ```

---

### Rules

- You may assume that input is in ascending or descending order (you may choose between `5,3` and `3,5`).
- You may also assume that the difference between the two integers is lower than 100.
- You may have a leading newline or a consistent leading space (on each line). Trailing spaces / newlines are fine as well.
- [Default Loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You can take input and provide output by [any standard mean](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in every language wins!

---

### Other Test Cases

- `1, 10`:

  ```
  1
   2
    3
     4
      5
       6
        7
         8
          9
           10
  ```
- `95, 103`:

  ```
  95
    96
      97
        98
          99
            100
               101
                  102
                     103
  ```
- `999999, 1000009`:

  ```
  999999
        1000000
               1000001
                      1000002
                             1000003
                                    1000004
                                           1000005
                                                  1000006
                                                         1000007
                                                                1000008
                                                                       1000009
  ```

Comment: Are leading spaces allowed, or does the first number *have* to be exactly on the left side of the screen?

Comment: @NathanShiraini Leading newlines are allowed

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125117/65836)

Comment: @StepHen This one's a bit harder though, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Are leading spaces allowed?

Comment: @Adnan You may have a leading newline or a consistent leading space on each line.

Comment: Are trailing newlines/spaces allowed?

Comment: @Titus Yup, that is allowed.

Answer (score 19):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Thanks to *Magic Octopus Urn* for saving a byte!

It somehow works, but honestly I have no idea why.

#### Code

```
Ÿvy.O=
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6I6ySj1/2///oy1NdRQMDUxjAQ)

#### Explanation

```
Ÿ          # Create the range [a, .., b] from the input array
 vy        # For each element
   .O      #   Push the connected overlapped version of that string using the
                 previous version of that string. The previous version initially
                 is the input repeated again. Somehow, when the input array is
                 repeated again, this command sees it as 1 character, which gives
                 the leading space before each line outputted. After the first
                 iteration, it reuses on what is left on the stack from the
                 previous iteration and basically attaches (or overlaps) itself 
                 onto the previous string, whereas the previous string is replaced 
                 by spaces and merged into the initial string. The previous string
                 is then discarded. We do not have to worry about numbers overlapping 
                 other numbers, since the incremented version of a number never
                 overlaps entirely on the previous number. An example of 123 and 456:
               
                 123
                    456
            
                 Which leaves us "   456" on the stack.
     =     #   Print with a newline without popping
```

Comment: `.O   = pop a,b    push connected_overlap(b) (deprecated)` - Oh, I guess?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, `.O` is extremely buggy and deprecated for over a year so I have no idea what works and what doesn't. I could swear that I needed `Î`, but that suddenly doesn't seem to be the case anymore (?). Thanks! :)

Comment: Btw, the `Î` was needed to reduce the maximum number of leading spaces to 1.

Comment: I... Wait... What, how...?

Comment: I don't really understand how this works such that it is so short. Can you add an explanation (in case you understand your own answer)?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder added

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:'\v'.join(map(str,range(a,b+1)))
```

Makes use of vertical tab to make the ladder effect. The way thet `\v` is rendered is console dependent, so it may not work everywhere (like TIO).
[image: running code]

Comment: Can you use a literal `\x0b` in your code to save a byte?

Comment: @DomHastings maybe, I don't know how though

Comment: I've just tested it and it appears to work. For getting the character into the file to test, I used Sublime Text and did a find and replace in regex mode for `\\v` and replaced with `\x0B` which shows up a `VT` character in its place for scoring you can either post a reversible hexdump (`xxd` or something) or just state that: "`\v` is a literal vertical tab", I think that would be fair. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 13):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>9</strike> 8 bytes

```
Ｆ…·ＮＮ⁺¶ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzMvOae0OLMsNSgxLz0VyC0oLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFA4WpqcikoBBRl5pVoOKakaCjF5CnpZGpqWv//b6BgaPJft@y/bnEOAA)

Link is to the verbose version of the code. Input in ascending order.

- 1 byte saved thanks to ASCII-only!

Comment: Nice, Charcoal wins this again!

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzMvOae0OLMsNSgxLz0VyC0oLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFA4WpqcikoBBRl5pVoaGsoxeQp6WRqalr//2@gYGjyX7fsv25xDgA)

Comment: **EDIT:** Charcoal got outgolfed... Wow

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder at least I know how my answer works. :-D

Answer (score 7):

## R, <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 61 bytes

```
function(a,b)for(i in a:b){cat(rep('',F),i,'
');F=F+nchar(i)}
```

Function that takes the start and end variable as arguments. Loops over the sequence, and prints each element, prepended with enough spaces. `F` starts as `FALSE=0`, and during each iteration, the amount of characters for that value is added to it. `F` decides the amount of spaces printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJMy2/SCNTITNPIdEqSbM6ObFEoyi1QENdXSdEUydTR51LXdM6xDZEOy85IxGoULP2f5qGoY6CkYHmfwA)

-8 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe

Comment: I see 70 bytes there. Using `scan()` twice it can be reduced to 67 bytes `for(i in scan():scan()){cat(rep(' ',F),i,'\n',sep='');F=F+nchar(i)}`.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to reset F, otherwise the function can be used only once in a new sessions. `F=0;for(i in scan():scan()){cat(rep(' ',F),i,'\n',sep='');F=F+nchar(i)}` (71 byte)

Comment: @djhurio Inside a function, that is not necessary, since F is only modified in its own namespace. Also, I count 69 bytes, using `nchar`.

Comment: Yet manually counting I do get 70. This is weird...

Comment: You are right about the function. `nchar('\n') == 1` ;)

Comment: ... that makes sense. sorta...

Comment: But replacing `\n` for an actual newline works too, and that doesn't cost two bytes apparently.

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJMy2/SCNTITNPIdEqSbM6ObFEoyi1QENdXSdEUydTR51LXdM6xDZEOy85IxGoULP2f5qGoY6CkYHmfwA "R – Try It Online") with the spec "consistent leading space"

Comment: Nice, I thought of abusing the automatic spacing of `cat`, but I couldn't think straight and figure it out for some reason.

Comment: @Giuseppe [One more byte](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgDADA3Vew0cYyNDoZXf0HEBu7FEPw/dVbr7scLq/Voc0gU0FpHTSohbwVrHlAvx6Ikc49nbPVO/@dGJGU4hTRBZiZeFnRPw)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,s=''):print s;b<a or f(a+1,b,' '*len(s)+`a`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1EnSafYVl1d06qgKDOvRKHYOskmUSG/CCSlbQiUVFdQ18pJzdMo1tROSEzQ/J@mYaBjZKD5HwA)

Comment: Wow, surprising recursive solution and out-golfs most python answers, +1.

Comment: Very good job Ruud, your solution is also OS and console-independent by not using the vertical tab character like Rod did.

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>90</s> <s>89</s> 85 bytes

```c#
s=>e=>{var r="";for(int g=0;e>s;g+=(s+++"").Length)r+="".PadLeft(g)+s+"\n";return r;}
```

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @LiefdeWen.*
*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @auhmaan.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZCxasMwEIZ3P4XQJKHGOLShGFVeCp1cCO3QpYtwzq4gPhWdEijBz@5KCbQpdPA3iEP6/uNHHa1Gj35GOwJ92g7Y6xdFGItTwRLd3hKx7Xm@3GQo2ug6dvRux56tQyF/nn6lzNMBuweH8eZqohgcDk3DemZmMg2Y5nS0gQXDue59EMlig6k0NKQHZQQppTiXZQs4xA8ZVBLLrd210EcxSEWKvyPXAeIhIAt6mnXxp8WjR/J7KN@Ci9A6BNGLSoqNlHqJt75bItb1fVKrapG8zuqirZts3i4rkDl3SNQ58m/mBdLX5cjVzqm4nNP8DQ)

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
namespace System
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<int, Func<int, string>> f = s => e =>
            {
                var r = "";
                for (int g = 0; e > s; g += (s++ + "").Length)
                    r += "".PadLeft(g) + s + "\n";

                return r;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f(0)(5));
            Console.WriteLine(f(0)(14));
            Console.WriteLine(f(997)(1004));
            Console.WriteLine(f(1)(10));
            Console.WriteLine(f(95)(103));
            Console.WriteLine(f(999999)(1000009));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, now you don't have 5k precisely ;D

Comment: 1 byte at `i<=e` to `e>i`

Comment: @LiefdeWen Thanks :)

Comment: I believe you can save more 4 bytes by removing the `i` and reusing the `s` instead

Comment: @auhmaan Thanks don't know why I never think of using the input variable.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 59, bytes

```
Grid[(DiagonalMatrix@Range[1+##]/. 0->""+1)-1,Spacings->0]&
```

**input**

> [10,15]

-3 bytes @JungHwanMin
problem with 0 fixed (see comments for details)
thanx to @ngenisis

Comment: Wow, an answer that actually contains the word *Diagonal*

Comment: You need to add `Spacings -> 0` if you want this to be character-exact.

Comment: The input is only non-negative, not guaranteed to be positive.

Comment: `Grid[(DiagonalMatrix@Range[1+##]/. 0->""+1)-1,Spacings->0]&` is the shortest way I could find to fix those problems

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
rD⁶ṁ$;¥\Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I5VHjtoc7G1WsDy2Nifz//78lGPw3NAABSwA)

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>166</s> <s>134</s> <s>95</s> 82 Bytes

### New Answer

Just as a function not as a whole program.

```
f(a,b){int s=0,i;while(a<=b){i=s;while(i--)printf(" ");s+=printf("%i\n",a++)-1;}}
```

Thanks to Falken for helping knock off 13 Bytes (and fix a glitch)!

Thanks to Steph Hen for helping knock off 12 Bytes!

Thanks to  Zacharý for help knock off 1 Byte!

### Old Answers

Got rid of the int before main and changed const char*v[] to char**v and got rid of return 0;

```
main(int c,char**v){int s=0;for(int a=atoi(v[1]);a<=atoi(v[2]);a++){for(int i=0;i<s;i++)printf(" ");printf("%i\n",a);s+=log10(a)+1;}}


int main(int c,const char*v[]){int s=0;for(int a=atoi(v[1]);a<=atoi(v[2]);a++){for(int i=0;i<s;i++)printf(" ");printf("%i\n",a);s+=log10(a)+1;}return 0;}
```

This is my first time golfing and I wanted to try something in C. Not sure if I formatted this correctly, but I had fun making it!

```
int main(int c, const char * v[]) {
    int s = 0;
    for(int a=atoi(v[1]); a<=atoi(v[2]); a++) {
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++) printf(" ");
        printf("%i\n",a);
        s += log10(a)+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

```
int s = 0; // Number of spaces for each line

for(int a=atoi(argv[1]); a<=atoi(argv[2]); a++) { // Loop thru numbers

for(int i=0; i<s; i++) printf(" "); // Add leading spaces

printf("%i\n",a); // Print number

s += log10(a)+1; // Update leading spaces
```

**Usage**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I believe you can rename `argc` and `argv` to one letter variables.

Comment: I think you can move the `int s=0` to the for loop, as in `for(int s=0;a<=b;a++)`.

Comment: Ahh your right thanks, I updated the post!

Comment: Using `int i=s;while(i--)` instead of `for(int i=0;i<s;i++)` for the inner loop will save two bytes.

Comment: Also, it looks like this fails if the starting number is zero.  Fortunately that can be fixed and the code can be made even shorter by using the return value of printf, like so: `s+=printf("%i\n",a)-1;`

Comment: Last one: both `s` and `i` can be combined into a single `int` declaration, saving two more bytes.  Here's the final code: `f(a,b){int s=0,i;while(a<=b){i=s;while(i--)printf(" ");s+=printf("%i\n",a++)-1;}}`

Comment: Ahhh your right forgot about log10 on 0 and negatives, I've updated the solution thanks!

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe88QhN3cwCAI2fxJFxMMD1m43aS320yczhh7F04Q6MCW7griLYfNHyz@qbm8CZQeRee9KBJSioIxOM3IX79CLoBtSODcSrO1C/Lw9R8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Rotate[""<>Table[ToString@i<>" ",{i,##}],-Pi/4]&
```

since there are so many answers, I thought this one should be included

**input**

> [0,10]

**output**
[image]

Comment: This isn't valid, is it? But +1 just for taking the title literally.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>81</s> 78 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`\b(1+)¶11\1
$1¶1$&
1+
$.& $.&
 (.+)
$.1$* 
+1`( *)(.+?)( +)¶
$1$2¶$1$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLOyEmScNQW/PQNkPDGEMuFUMgQ0WNyxAoqaemAMRcChp62ppAnqGKlgKXtmGChoKWJlDIXlNDAaQNqEXF6NA2IGn8/78Fl6ERAA) Takes input as a newline-separated list of two integers. Edit: Saved 3 bytes by stealing the range-expansion code from my answer to [Do we share the prime cluster?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147254) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert both inputs to unary.

```
+`\b(1+)¶11\1
$1¶1$&
```

While the last two elements (a, b) of the list differ by more than 1, replace them with (a, a+1, b). This expands the list from a tuple into a range.

```
1+
$.& $.&
```

Convert back to decimal in duplicate.

```
 (.+)
$.1$*
```

Convert the duplicate copy to spaces.

```
+1`( *)(.+?)( +)¶
$1$2¶$1$3
```

Cumulatively sum the spaces from each line to the next.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

-1 thanks to [Zacharý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%c3%bd).

Assumes `⎕IO←0` for zero based counting. Takes the lower bound as left argument and the upper bound as right argument.

```apl
{↑⍵↑⍨¨-+\≢¨⍵}(⍕¨⊣+∘⍳1--)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/0vygVT1o7aJj3q3gskVh1boasc86lx0aAVQqFbjUe9UIKtrsfajjhmPejcb6upq/v9voFCSr2BowmVpaQ5mGRiYcBlCWFyWphCGMVAWBKAKgMASAA)

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function between the arguments:

`-` subtract the upper lower from the upper bound

`1-` subtract that from one (i.e. 1 + ∆)

`⊣+∘⍳` left lower bound plus the integers 0 through that

`⍕¨` format (stringify) each

`{`…`}` apply the following anonymous on that (represented by ⍵):

`≢¨` length of each (number)

`+\` cumulative sum

`-` negate

`⍵↑⍨¨` for each stringified number, take that many characters from the end (pads with spaces)

`↑` mix list of strings into character matrix

Comment: Could `+-⍨` be `--`?

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### C++, <s>167</s> 165 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<string>
#define S std::string
S d(int l,int h){S r;for(int m=0,i=l,j;i<=h;){for(j=0;j<m;++j)r+=32;S t=std::to_string(i++);r+=t;r+=10;m+=t.size();}return r;}
```

Comment: 1. Could you move the `int m=0,i=l,j` to the first `for` loop to save a byte? 2. Can you change `r+=t;r+=10` to `r+=t+10`? 3. I beat someone, yay.

Comment: @Zacharý I can do `r+=t+=10` but not `r+=t+10`, it gave me an error

Comment: But `r+=t+=10` does work? Wouldn't that affect `t.size()`?

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, it works, with only +, it says it can't find an overload with int as parameter, but with += it uses the overload with the char

Comment: Oh, could you move the `++i` to the `std::to_string(i)` as `std::to_string(i++)` to save one more byte?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>65 63 62</s> 61 bytes

*-2 bytes Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder: `exec` doesn't need braces*

*-1 bye thanks to @Zacharý: `print s*' '` as `print' '*s`*

```python
def f(m,n,s=0):exec(n-m+1)*"print' '*s+`m`;s+=len(`m`);m+=1;"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1cnT6fY1kDTKrUiNVkjTzdX21BTS6mgKDOvRF1BXatYOyE3wbpY2zYnNU8DyNS0ztW2NbRW@p@mYaBjaKL5HwA)

Comment: You do not need the braces for exec. ``m,n=input();s=0;exec(n-m+1)*"print s*' '+`m`;s+=len(`m`);m+=1;"`` suffices.

Comment: I think you can change `print s*' '` to `print' '*s` to save one byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
V}FQ
=k+*dlkN
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%7DFQ%0A%3Dk%2B%2adlkN&input=999999%2C+1000009&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## [LOGO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), 53 bytes

```
[for[i ? ?2][repeat ycor[type "\ ]pr :i fd count :i]]
```

There is no "Try it online!" link because all online LOGO interpreter does not support template-list.

That is a template-list (equivalent of lambda function in other languages).

Usage:

```
apply [for[i ? ?2][repeat ycor[type "\ ]pr :i fd count :i]] [997 1004]
```

(`apply` calls the function)

will print

```
997
   998
      999
         1000
             1001
                 1002
                     1003
                         1004
```

Note:

This uses turtle's `ycor` (Y-coordinate) to store the number of spaces needed to type, therefore:

- The turtle need to be set to home in its default position and heading (upwards) before each invocation.
- `window` should be executed if `ycor` gets too large that the turtle moves off the screen. Description of `window` command: `if the turtle is asked to move past the boundary of the graphics window, it will move off screen.`, unlike the default setting `wrap`, which `if the turtle is asked to move past the boundary of the FMSLogo screen window, it will "wrap around" and reappear at the opposite edge of the window.`

Explanation:

```
for[i ? ?2]        Loop variable i in range [?, ?2], which is 2 input values
repeat ycor        That number of times
type "\            space character need to be escaped to be typed out.
pr :i              print the value of :i with a newline
fd count :i        increase turtle's y-coordinate by the length of the word :i. (Numbers in LOGO are stored as words)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
òV
£¯Y ¬ç +X
```

Takes input in either order and always returns the numbers in ascending order, as an array of lines.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=8lYKo69ZIKznICtY&inputs=MAo1,MAoxNA==,OTk3CjEwMDQ=,MQoxMA==,OTUKMTAz,OTk5OTk5CjEwMDAwMDk=&flags=LVI=) with the `-R` flag to join the array with newlines.

### Explanation

Implicit input of `U` and `V`.

```
òV
£
```

Create inclusive range `[U, V]` and map each value to...

```
¯Y ¬ç
```

The values before the current (`¯Y`), joined to a string (`¬`) and filled with spaces (`ç`).

```
+X
```

Plus the current number. Resulting array is implicitly output.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 62 bytes

Takes input as integers, in ascending order, using currying syntax. Returns an array of strings.

```
x=>y=>[...Array(++y-x)].map(_=>s="".padEnd(s.length)+x++,s="")
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=

x=>y=>[...Array(++y-x)].map(_=>s="".padEnd(s.length)+x++,s="")

)(i.value=93)(j.value=105).join`\n`
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(Math.min(i.value,j.value))(Math.max(i.value,j.value)).join`\n`
```

```css
label,input{font-family:sans-serif}input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:100px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>x: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>y: </label><input id=j type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Ÿʒ¾ú=þv¼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f8wNWFiMWX//8W4ypLCvsO6PcO@dsK8//85NQoxMDM)

-2 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

Comment: Ahh, that is very clever. You can replace `vy` by `ʒ` and `gF` by `v` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Adnan I didn't expect the good old `ʒ` trick to still be used...

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

*-3 bytes Thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)*

```c
t(x,v){while(x<=v)printf("%d\v",x++);}
```

Works on RedHat6, accessed via PuTTY

[image: Proof]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Eo0KnTLO6PCMzJ1Wjwsa2TLOgKDOvJE1DSTUlpkxJp0JbW9O69n9uYmaehmZ1iYaBjimIDwA)

Comment: This doesn't produce correct output.

Comment: it's tricky, output to a file and then use `more` on that file

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello You must provide the full code in order for us to be able to run your program. If you do not provide a working test ground / do not provide instructions on how to run your program such that it produces correct output, please delete this answer.

Comment: Linefeed may return to begin of line, it depends. This does work when it does not.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Edited

Comment: @user202729 char11 is vertical Tab

Comment: Ok, I don't remember ASCII. `printf("%d\xB",x++)` should work and save some bytes.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Eo0KnTLO6PCMzJ1Wjwsa2TLOgKDOvJE1DSTUlpkxJp0JbW9O69n9uYmaehmZ1iYaBjimIDwA)

Comment: `printf("%d\v",x++)` should also save one more byte

Comment: @ASCII-only thanks!

Comment: Can you use a literal `\x0b` in your code to save another byte?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <strike>78</strike> <strike>77</strike> 79 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):
 for i in range(a,b+1):print sum(len(`j`)for j in range(i))*' '+`i`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDoAgDADA3Vd0k6qDMvKaYgQt0WoQB19fw@R6uest2ylWdQkRovHDjK6BeGZgYIHsZQ1V@wndlVkK3M9h9iCGEmF96X@M2LXQ9sSk0YyDHVE/)

`f(A, B)` will print the portion of the axis between A and B inclusive.

First time I answer a challenge!

Uses and abuses Python 2's backticks to count the number of spaces it has to add before the number.

-1 byte thanks to [Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

+2 because I forgot a `+1`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! nice first answer. ``sum(len(`j`)) for`` can become ``sum(len(`j`)for``, -1 bytes

Comment: To make this answer valid, you must replace `range(a,b)` with `range(a,b+1)`, because Python has semi inclusive ranges.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. What's more surprising is that I *did* add that +1 when I made my tests! No wonder I had 2 bytes missing when I typed it into TiO...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
f=(x,y,s='')=>y>=x?s+`
`+f(x+1,y,s.replace(/./g,' ')+x):s
```

Comment: 55 bytes: `y=>g=(x,s='')=>y<x?s:s+'\n'+g(x+1,s.replace(/./g,' ')+x)` Call with currying with the integers reversed: `f(103)(95)`.

Comment: 54 bytes: `x=>y=>g=(s='')=>y<x?s:s+'\n'+g(s.replace(/./g,' ')+x++)` Call as `f(x)(y)()`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <strike>60</strike> 59 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Mr.Xcoder for defining my s=0 as an optional variable in my function.

```python
def f(l,u,s=0):
 while l<=u:print' '*s+`l`;s+=len(`l`);l+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixCoAgFEDRva94W5oOWjRY@S8NKQoPk1Sir7fsTocbn@zOMNZ6GAuWIC88aUGXDm7n0QBuuizx8iH30A@J7biviWk0gXykKzItqyWSgxS0s0TNXIrp11/7LUXrCw)

I think it is possible to transfer this into a lambda version, but I do not know how. I also think that there is some sort of mapping between the spaces and the length of the current number, but this I also did not figure out yet. So I think there still is room for improvement.

What i did was creating a range from the lowerbound `l`to the upper bound `u` printing each line with a space multiplied with a number `s`. I am increasing the multiplier with the length of the current number.

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcixCoAgFEDRva94W5oOWjRY@S8NKQoPk1Sir7fsTocbn@zOMNZ6GAuWIC88aUGXDm7n0QBuuizx8iH30A@J7biviWk0gXykKzItqyWSgxS0s0TNXIrp11/7LUXrCw)

Comment: [Alternative 59 bytes](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEEDRfaeQNs2kgRYtSrxLUErBYJIFdXor/@rxw3Ouu29TWqxjDkhcIhqJo73tXIZj82fFqjryiSYduSHr4SNq4kbpsoarIUwOlGBKYuFg6IWSXVbu/38Dphc)

Comment: I'll figure out you did with that "exec"-version later this day. Maybe it will help me in future codings. Thanks

Comment: [Lambda version, 62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIUenVKfY1sBKXUFdSyPHrlQzv0g9Jk9dG8Qv1k7ISdBO08jRNgSp0s5JzdMAimhq/i8oyswrUUjTMNRRMDTQ5IJxLU11DA2MkfhgAFIDApaa/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
vii&:"t~@Vh
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vywzU81KqaTOISzj/39Lcy5DA1MA)

#### Explanation

This works by generating a string for each number and concatenating it with a logically-negated copy of the previous string. Thus char 0 is prepended 0 as many times as the length of the previous string. Char 0 is displayed as a space, and each string is displayed on a different line

```
v       % Concatenate stack (which is empty): pushes []
ii      % Input two numbers
&:      % Range between the two numbers
"       % For each
  t     %   Duplicate
  ~     %   Logical negation. This gives a vector of zeros
  @     %   Push current number
  V     %   Convert to string
  h     %   Concatenate with the vector of zeros, which gets automatically 
        %   converted into chars.
        % End (implicit). Display stack (implicit), each string on a diferent
        % line, char 0 shown as space
```

Answer (score 2):

## D, <s>133</s> <s>127</s> <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>121</s> 119 bytes

```d
import std.conv,std.stdio;void f(T)(T a,T b,T s=0){for(T j;j++<s;)' '.write;a.writeln;if(a-b)f(a+1,b,s+a.text.length);}
```

Jelly and APL were taken.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNDsIgEEb3PQW7QkBS1ugtuAAI6DQtmDJpTYxnx1EX30/e4sXeYX3UDVnDqK@17Op7KFDtXiGyzJ3gjnnlWKC0yyReuW6EZjtLeW5WjGzUxwaYrP/vUixk7k9BUEujgmrSa0xP1EsqN7wL@x6Gn371UDgZuVFmItz7Bw)

If you're fine with console-dependent results (goes off the same principle as Giacomos's C answer) here's one for <s>72</s> 71 bytes:

```d
import std.stdio;void f(T)(T a,T b){while(a<=b){a++.write;'\v'.write;}}
```

### How? (Only D specific tricks)

- `f(T)(T a,T b,T s=0)` D's template system can infer types
- `for(T j;j++<s;)` Integers default to `0`.
- `' '.write;a.writeln` D lets you call `fun(arg)` like `arg.fun` (one of the few golfy things D has)
- `a.text.length` Same as above, and D also allows you to call a method with no parameters as if it was a property (`text` is conversion to string)
- One thing that might be relevant (I didn't use this though) newlines can be in strings!

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16 bytes

```
ÀñÙywÒ $pça/jd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4Y2HZ1aWH56koFLAeHi5UKJ@Vsr//6b/DU0B)

This would be way easier if I could take `start` `end - start` but I think that's changing the challenge a bit too much.

This takes the start number as input in the buffer and the end number as an argument.  It actually creates the ladder from `start` to `start + end` and then deletes everything after the end number.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 19 bytes

**Note: `\x0b` is counted as one byte.**

Along with others, I thought using cursor movements would be the shortest route, this does mean it doesn't work on TIO:

```pl
print"$_\x0b"for<>..<>
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -e 'print"$_\x0b"for<>..<>' <<< '5
10'
5
 6
  7
   8
    9
     10
```

Comment: Nice, haven't seen Perl at all in a while. Could you add a testing link? Additionally, I was wondering what the `1..` does there, since you are given two integers.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah, `1..` was me not fully reading the spec, that's fixed now! As for testing it online, because the output contains the vertical tab, it doesn't render as expected. Trying to see if I can find a renderer that does support control chars... If not, that might be my new project!

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 4](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-release-process/), 115 bytes

I think nobody would have posted a Swift solution anyway...

```swift
func f(l:Int,b:Int){for i in l...b{print(String(repeating:" ",count:(l..<i).map{String($0).count}.reduce(0,+)),i)}}
```

[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597f2a514ed958681150d0b9)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
òV åÈç +Y
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8lYg5cjnICtZ&input=OTk3LCAxMDA0Ci1S) Returns an array of lines; `-R` flag included to join on newlines for easier viewing.

#### Explanation

```
 òV åÈ   ç +Y
UòV åXY{Xç +Y}   Ungolfed
                 Implicit: U, V = inputs, P = empty string
UòV              Create the range [U, U+1, ..., V-1, V].
    åXY{     }   Cumulative reduce: Map each previous result X and current item Y to:
        Xç         Fill X with spaces.
           +Y      Append Y.
                 Implicit: output result of last expression
```

---

Old version, 10 bytes:

```
òV £P=ç +X
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8lYgo1A95yArWA==&input=OTk3LCAxMDA0Ci1S)

```
 òV £  P= ç +X
UòV mX{P=Pç +X}  Ungolfed
                 Implicit: U, V = inputs, P = empty string
UòV              Create the range [U, U+1, ..., V-1, V].
    mX{       }  Map each item X to:
         Pç        Fill P with spaces.
            +X     Append X.
       P=          Re-set P to the result.
                   Implicitly return the same.
                 Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Dang, I had just come up with the same solution as an improvement to my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 79 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{for(String s="";a<=b;System.out.printf("%"+s.length()+"d\n",a++))s+=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxasMwFAB3f4UQFCTkiJbSoSjO0E4dOmVsOzzLkiPXlozeU6AEf7urIdMNd9wEVzik1cVp@N3tDIjsE0Jkt2Yt/RwsQwKquKYwsKUacaYc4vj1A3lEWbupHnShMGtfoqWQon4L7yliWVw@fkRyo8vtnSfmWbcLaHt5ON18yvcdw45zA8euN@c/JLfoVEivVZEX/IEr1LOLI12EVHz4jrwFpaRE1YHZdtN4Dda6lcTrS8ueHp@labZm2/8B)

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `(a,b)->` to `b->a->`. (And you could save three more bytes by going to Java 10 and changing `String` to `var`.) [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY7BSsQwFEX3/YpHQEjINCjiQjLtRhBcuJqlunhtk5raJiV5KQxDv712RHeu7oV7uJwBFyyH7mtrR0wJXtH5SwEw52Z0LSRC2mMJroNpn/iJovP92wdg7JO4kgDDfqEyuVHZ7Ftywavn33J88WR6Ew//QU/BpzyZ@AfVNViotqassawvNkS@YIRUMabxWDX6dE5kJhUyqXm3IMvZDZNJjcb39MmFZN27ZweUUogkK9TrdtXTxY@lVTjP45nf3d4LhW1rZuKPD0Lv41qs2zc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
a%b=scanl((.show).(++).(' '<$))""[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1ybY4OTEvR0NDrzgjv1xTT0NbG0ioK6jbqGhqKilFJ@rpJcX@z03MzFOwVSgoLQkuKVLQUyjNy8nMSy1WUFEwVTU2/Q8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [NotQuiteThere](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/NotQuiteThere), 5 bytes

```
yr-11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyss@f@/skjX0PD/f0NDLnMA)

Uses the vertical tab trick in Rod's python answer, so doesn't really work on TIO. Input is taken in descending order (`11, 7`)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 25 bytes

```
[:,:|A=space$(_lA|)+!a$?A
```

Explanation:

```
[:     FOR a = <input 1 from cmd line>
,:|    TO <input 2 from cmd line>
A=         SET A$ to 
 space$      a number of spaces equal to 
 (_lA|)      the current length of A$ (starts as "" = 0)
+!a$         and add a cast-to string of the current loop iterator
?A     PRINT A$
           Loop auto-closed by QBIC
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[*a..b]*?\v}
```

Just for reference, but does not work on TIO:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6WitRTy8pVss@pqz2f0FpSbFCWrShjqFp7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 49 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args;$a..$b|%{$l=($z=" "*$l+$_).length;$z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyVRRyXJViWxKL3YWiVRT08lqUa1WiXHVkOlylZJQUlLJUdbJV5TLyc1L70kw1qlqvb///@Wlub/DQ0MTAA)

Takes input as two command-line arguments, `$a` and `$b`, forms a range `..` out of them, then loops `|%{}` over that range. Each iteration, we construct a string `$z` of a certain number of spaces `" "*$l` concatenated with our current number `$_`. We then pull out the `.length` of that, re-store it into `$l` for next time, and leave `$z` on the pipeline. Output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 10

```
seq -s^K $@
```

Here `^K` is a literal vertical tab and control character. The xxd dump of this script is as follows - use `xxd -r` to regenerate the actual script:

```
00000000: 7365 7120 2d73 0b20 2440                 seq -s. $@
```

Input range is given as two integers at the command-line.

Not sure if much of an explanation is needed here - `seq` simply does the counting (from `a` to `b`, passed in the `$@` parameter), with `-s` specifying the separator as a vertical tab.  This causes the next number to be printed after the previous one, down one line, as required.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 46 bytes

```hs
a%b=[([a..x-1]>>=show>>" ")++show x|x<-[a..b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTZaIzpRT69C1zDWzs62OCO/3M5OSUFJU1sbxFaoqKmw0QUpSIqN/Z@bmJmnYKtQUFoSXFKkoKdQmpeTmZdarKCiYKBqZPAfAA) Usage: `0%20`. Returns a list of lines. Use `putStr . unlines $ 0%20` for pretty-printing.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 51 bytes

```
sj0skp[32Plkll1+dsl<S]sS[0sldZlk+sklSx1+pdlj>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b6hgaPq/OMugOLsg2tgoICc7J8dQO6U4xyY4tjg42qA4JyUqJ1u7ODsnuMJQuyAlJ8vONzal2Lfi/38A)

This pretty much has to be suboptimal, my brain is clearly still in Monday mode.
Pretty much just macro `S` printing spaces, and macro `M` doing the rest of the work. Register `l` restarts at zero spaces before running `S`, and compares against register `k`, which we always increment by the number of digits of top-of-stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 31 + <s>1 (-a)</s> 0 = <s>43</s> 31 bytes

```perl
map{say$l=$l=~y// /cr.$_}<>..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saC6OLFSJccWiOoq9fUV9JOL9FTia23s9PRs7P7/t7Q04DI0MDT4l19QkpmfV/xf19dUD8gHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 50 bytes

```
<<f=>(x,y){<<s=""#i:x->y+1{s+i#i!=0{s+=" "i\=10}}}

f(95, 103)
```

[Try it online!](http://felixguo.me/#wendyScript)

Only issue is once you get past 100000, numbers are outputted in scientific notation (which I should probably change to always display in full form). The online syntax highlighter also dislikes `""` but it *is* parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 bytes

```
proc P a\ b {while \$a<=$b {puts [format %[incr i [string len $a]]d $a];incr a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYm9DoIwFIV3n@IMdW@jxDTqO7AXhmtFbVILKTUMhGev93KG8/cVH2ud8ujRgjo8sC6fEAd0im53xXP6lRnuNeYvFRxdSD4jwM0lh/RGHBIU9f1T/LpD2rbaQqM5iJszh7UXGK2lGi7yNJynHYmEsmz9Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 43 bytes

```
INPUT A,B
FOR I=A TO B?" "*C;I;
C=CSRX?NEXT
```

**Explanation**

```
?" "*C;I;    'Print C (initially 0) spaces followed by I, with no newline.
C=CSRX       'Set C to the horizontal cursor position.
?            'Print a newline.
```

Comment: This is only 43 bytes.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Not sure how I miscounted there.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 85 bytes

```
	M =INPUT
	N =INPUT
O	OUTPUT =S M
	S =S DUPL(' ',SIZE(M))
	M =LT(M,N) M + 1 :S(O)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NXwdbTLyA0hIvTD8by5/QPDQEyFGyDFXy5OINBtEtogI@GuoK6TrBnlKuGr6YmF0inT4iGr46fpoKvgraCoYJVsIa/Jpern8v//wZchiYA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7.1, 66 bytes

```
for([,$i,$z]=$argv;$i<=$z;)printf("%".($e+=strlen($i))."d
",$i++);
```

Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c8b917bb86c6b2e78c8b17f2cb53b833c26bb63).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,n,z:'\n'+' '*(a+n-z)+str(a)+f(a+1,b,n+len(str(a))-1,z) if a!=b+1 else ''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCsIwEIXhvaeIq2ScKSRIkAq9iZsJJliIY2mzMZePKSK4e@/jX97l8ZJza2nK/Ax3VkyBhOpV30SjVvpkGGWogFtZDQOm/t3eYI5ivgiDowpqToqPU0CnYt6i0rot6yzFJGPJebJkAQ4/8uQ6kP@jcbx0tHvZJ0D7AA)

Answer (score 0):

K3, 29 bytes

```
{`0:{(1_0+\#:'$:'x)$'x}x+!y-x}
```

example:

```
  {`0:{(1_0+\#:'$:'x)$'x}x+!y-x}[1;15]
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
      7
       8
        9
         10
           11
             12
               13
                 14
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) + CSS, 72 + 12 = 84 bytes

```js
a=>b=>{for(i=0;a<=b;)document.write(`<x>${"<br>".repeat(i++)+a++}</x>`)}
```

```css
x{float:left
```

Takes input in currying syntax with the smaller number first. Outputs the result to the page in HTML.

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=

a=>b=>{for(i=0;a<=b;)document.write(`<x>${"<br>".repeat(i++)+a++}</x>`)}

f(0)(8)
f(5)(14)
f(998)(1003)
```

```css
x{float:left
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 41 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `A1:B1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=[A1]To[B1]:?spc(j)i:j=j+len(i):Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC ~73 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 LET X=SGN PI
 2 LET Y=CODE "="
 3 LET A=NOT PI
 4 FOR I=X TO Y
 5 PRINT TAB A;I
 6 LET A=A+LEN STR$ I
 7 NEXT I
```

This newer solution has fewer bytes but slightly slower. `SGN PI` is `1`, `CODE "="` is `20` and `NOT PI` is `0`; the `PRINT TAB` command does what you might expect, except a `TAB` in ZX81 land is 1 space; `A` is increased by the length of the `I` variable once converted to a string.

#### Old answer (~98 tokenized bytes)

```
 1 LET X=1
 2 LET Y=20
 3 LET A$=""
 4 FOR I=X TO Y
 5 PRINT A$;I
 6 FOR T=1 TO LEN STR$ I
 7 LET A$=A$+" "
 8 NEXT T
 9 NEXT I
```

I'm using the most expensive methods here in terms of bytes (i.e., `SGN PI` is 1, and counts as two bytes in ZX81 land, whereas `1` counts as four bytes), so I could cut the byte count by increasing the typing and making the listing less readable, and slower.

The 'spacing' works by converting the I number to a string and taking the string literal length, using that in a `FOR/NEXT` loop as the destination [line 6]. `X` is the start number, and `Y` is the end number.

There are a few limitations to consider, such as only having a 32 columns display by default, and only allowing 22 rows without some `POKE`ing. Also, the screen doesn't scroll when it is full unless you tell it to, with the command `SCROLL`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 56+3 = 59 bytes

```
1</+1$,a\.0e:/o" "\
:1>$:a)?/~}r+\1-:?/~r:n&:&:&=?;&1+ao
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39BGX9tQRScxRs8g1Uo/X0lBKYbLytBOxSpR016/rrZIO8ZQ1wrIKrLKU7MCQlt7azVD7cT8////6xYnpgMA)

+3 bytes for -v. Not sure whether I actually need to add this for a function, but better to err on the side of caution

#### How It Works

```
1<................\     Initialises the stack with the space counter on top of the inputted numbers
................../~...

...................                  Print the first number
....................r:n&:&:&=?;&1+ao If the first number is equal to the end, exit program. Otherwise increment the first number and print a newline

../+1$,a\... Count the number of digits in the number
:1>$:a)?/... By incrementing a counter and dividing the number by 10 until it's below 10

........\.0e:/... Add the amount of digits to the counter
.......?/~}r+\...

............./o" "\     Print the counter amount of spaces and loop around again
.............\1-:?/~...
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 61 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,n=-1):
 for a in range(a,b+1):print(" "*(n:=n+1),a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNI1EnSSfPVtdQ04pLIS2/SCFRITNPoSgxLz0VJKUNFC8oyswr0VBSUNLSyLOyzQMK6SRq/v8PAA)