# Do we share the prime cluster?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, decision-problem, primes

The *prime cluster* of an integer **N** higher than **2** is defined as the pair formed by the highest prime **strictly** lower than **N** and the lowest prime **strictly** higher than **N**.

Note that following the definition above, if the integer is a prime itself, then its prime cluster is the pair of the primes *preceding* and *succeeding* it.

## Task

Given two integers integers **N**, **M** (**N, M ≥ 3**), output a [truthy / falsy value](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info) based on whether **N** and **M** have the same prime cluster.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the aim is to reduce your byte count as much as possible. Thus, the shortest code in every [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073) wins.

## Test cases / Examples

For instance, the prime cluster of **9** is `[7, 11]`, because:

- **7** is the highest prime strictly lower than **9**, and
- **11** is the lowest prime strictly higher than **9**.

Similarly, the  the prime cluster of **67** is `[61, 71]` (note that **67** is a prime).

**Truthy pairs**

```
8, 10
20, 22
65, 65
73, 73
86, 84
326, 318
513, 518
```

**Falsy pairs**

```
4, 5
6, 8
409, 401
348, 347
419, 418
311, 313
326, 305
```

Comment: Do the truthy / falsy values have to be two distinct values or can one define a mapping from their program's output to a truthy / falsy value and output (potentially infinitely) many different values?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Truthy/Falsy per [tag:decision-problem] definition, not necessarily consistent but distict and truthy/falsy

Answer (score 17):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> <s>4</s> <s>3</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
rÆPE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/ocFuA6////y3@GxoAAA) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY29DcJQDIR7pvAAlnj@eYkZANHSR6@kQanoaClYhYYtsgmLGNtpTp9Pd@f7bV2f7o/tfT379uHj7/W9uC8LgCEANTwAALdg5uKpY0nyLFiSbFOwabJwsJAld4pMJxtxxKhGCPYyZAEqpO2EIVRljceic/mU/j4kRDkqY/wB).

#### How it works

```
rÆPE    Main link. Arguments: N, M
r       Yield the range of integers between N and M, inclusive.
 ÆP     For each integer, yield 1 if it is prime, 0 otherwise.
   E    Yield 1 if all items are equal (none in the range were prime,
        or there's only one item).
```

Works because two numbers have different prime clusters iff there is a prime between them, or either number is itself prime; *unless* both numbers are the same, in which case `E` returns `1` anyway (all items in a single-item array are equal).

Comment: Your programs source doesn’t look friendly...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>103</strike> <strike>95</strike> 91 bytes

```python
lambda*z:len({*z})<2or[1for i in range(min(z),max(z)+1)if all(i%k for k in range(2,i))]<[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LcsIwDEXX9Vdow4wNWviVBwx8iZvpGJq0HhKHSbKAMP321AoLVjqS7pXu7TH99tEszelzaX13/vbb@dDWkT@385846n5wqukHCBAiDD7@1LwLkc8CO39PZadEaMC3LQ@bK5Dy@lZqDEJURyerZarH6evix3qEEzjmSgQlK2ROSwStifIMIc@ICoNQGKIyRygtkdEJjSqJM5UE2YttotWdhGsv9whWqtVj0xtji3WuaP7yGKXoFn2oGKPQd3xQ7HfKA/u4DSFOvOFpJ8TyDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 52 bytes

```perl6
{[eqv] @_».&{(($_...0),$_..*)».first(*.is-prime)}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##hVBLasMwEN37FEMwQUoVYVnyp5gWr3qC7EIITiqDwUkcywkU45N114u5o0gtdNWV3sy8z2g63bfpfDMa7ik/FsHpA5bHy7uGl3nc6ut9B@X@65MvR0LCPec8osy@K4rNuunNQFa8Meuub06aTtOM@nLob6gHEgCQnIFAjYVxxCCOHU4TBmnicCYZZNLhPGWQK4dljIUUuasSgbTkUdHHmmVdteY3R@HQW6ODQyp6ZqAi4e0U7iJV5mfCzn7MpRA2Sjpze42NNkMRdG119v958oFFUF9631u/AoGwYhAegMKITo0Bez2CzfBAGWyQxmCxdaTdIpic3O3@v/7N8v4azN8)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit slurpy input ｢@_｣

  [eqv]               # see if each sub list is equivalent

    @_».&{            # for each value in the input

      (

        ( $_ ... 0 ), # decreasing Seq
          $_ ..  *    # Range

      )».first(*.is-prime) # find the first prime from both the Seq and Range

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sub><s>57</s></sub> 54 bytes

```ruby
->n,m{[*n..m,*m..n].all?{|x|?1*x=~/^(11+)\1+$/}||n==m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7NToQwFIX38xQ3RBJlaodLy48mdR7CZa0JoxAWgKZAMhOKr469sHThql9O7vl67HS5rbVaH1961s066jnvWNRx3htetu15dld3xuiqfk7v94jHhzc83p0W53qlumUd7TQ2N1CgdcEAY8NAJzGDJCHKUgZZSpQLBrkgKjIGhSQSiUeBBXGK/iD1bA512Q67Ufpo0/gGvTJ@YiBj3MrS/ydkvuVI@S4SiCQVXvQ9jQMEr83X1H7CpQK/tXoODvtkXpUfDczOOtjvwgHCIQi1ZbWOrDHLnz4NI8E28P/@@gs)

Uses the horrible regex primality test from [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57668/11071) (which I had forgotten about until I clicked on it) to the related question [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime). Since we have N, M ≥ 3, the check for 1 can be removed from the pattern, making the byte count less than using the built-in.

Note: The regex primality test is pathologically, hilariously inefficient. I believe it's at least O(n!), though I don't have time to figure it right now. It took twelve seconds for it to check 100,001, and was grinding for five or ten minutes on 1,000,001 before I canceled it. *Use/abuse at your own risk.*

Comment: At that rate it is likely `n²`. You know, `100001! = 2824257650254427477772164512240315763832679701040485762827423875723843380680572028502730496931545301922349718873479336571104510933085749261906300669827923360329777024436472705878118321875571799283167659071802605510878659379955675120386166847407407122463765792082065493877636247683663198828626954833262077780844919163487776145463353109634071852657157707925315037717734498612061347682956332369235999129371094504360348686870713719732258380465223614176068 ... (Warning: The output exceeded 128 KiB and was truncated.)` which will take millenia to run.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 58 bytes

```
\b(.+)¶\1\b

.+
$*
O`
+`\b(1+)¶11\1
$1¶1$&
A`^(11+)\1+$
^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JklDT1vz0LYYw5gkLi49bS4VLS7/BC7tBKCEIUjC0DDGkEvFEMhQUeNyTIjTMAQKxxhqq3DFqfz/b2xkyWVsaAEA) Explanation:

```
\b(.+)¶\1\b
```

If both inputs are the same, simply delete everything, and fall through to output 1 at the end.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
O`
```

Sort into order.

```
+`\b(1+)¶11\1
$1¶1$&
```

Expand to a range of all the numbers.

```
A`^(11+)\1+$
```

Delete all composite numbers.

```
^$
```

If there are no numbers left, output 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>153</s> 146 bytes

```
i,B;n(j){for(B=i=2;i<j;)B*=j%i++>0;return!B;}
#define g(l,m,o)for(l=o;n(--l););for(m=o;n(++m););
a;b;c;d;h(e,f){g(a,b,e)g(c,d,f)return!(a-c|b-d);}
```

-7 from Jonathan Frech

Defines a function `h` which takes in two `int`s and returns `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHNcoIwEMfvPMXWDjOJLDOEoNKu9MBrWA4YPkQFO0h7oTw7TSyDXjxssr/9bzbZjXJLpcaxwpgaduR9cWlZHFWRT9X2SDxeRke7cpwPj9q8@26bl5gG6zXLi6rJoWRnrPHCzaFzdNEVXPfMiZMJ1LeA49QmYKW0J0UZHViOBe9LluIec14yhZkOTMVZ6qrfvZtxGsaq6aDLr911l@xkAhH0FkAfovAQxIAGfO36/ozrFYKxCTcSwdiE4RrDYCbpr1GKcOaVkLh64AB1IW@qi@HsB94bBp6YWQYhymBz14XWxT1fCqHvkYatgSzTVJ1WDTNO2pYKQR3SFpZLDT/81qMeHtz0k27aI71tQUgCxzn9JwB8tVov2MLO0M7ewc4givT62Sxwmtkp2XnJAwgNB/ZM4w/kJ/q7APRzxz8)

`n` is a function that returns 1 if its argument is not prime.

`g` is a macro that sets its first and second arguments to the next prime less than and greater than (respectively) it's third argument

`h` does `g` for both inputs and checks whether the outputs are the same.

Comment: `return a==c&&b==d;` can be `return!(a-c|b-d);`.

Comment: [146 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZHNcoIwEMfvPMXWDjOJLDOEoNKu9MBrWA4YPkQFO0h7oTw7TSyDXjxssr/9bzbZjXJLpcaxwpgaduR9cWlZHFWRT9X2SDxeRke7cpwPj9q8@26bl5gG6zXLi6rJoWRnrPHCzaFzdNEVXPfMiZMJ1LeA49QmYKW0J0UZHViOBe9LluIec14yhZkOTMVZ6qrfvZtxGsaq6aDLr911l@xkAhH0FkAfovAQxIAGfO36/ozrFYKxCTcSwdiE4RrDYCbpr1GKcOaVkLh64AB1IW@qi@HsB94bBp6YWQYhymBz14XWxT1fCqHvkYatgSzTVJ1WDTNO2pYKQR3SFpZLDT/81qMeHtz0k27aI71tQUgCxzn9JwB8tVov2MLO0M7ewc4givT62Sxwmtkp2XnJAwgNB/ZM4w/kJ/q7APRzxz8).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Fixed the TIO link.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(a)(b)`. Returns `0` or `1`.

```js
a=>b=>a==b|!(g=k=>a%--k?g(k):k<2||a-b&&g(a+=a<b||-1))(a)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>b=>a==b|!(g=k=>a%--k?g(k):k<2||a-b&&g(a+=a<b||-1))(a)

console.log('Truthy')
console.log(f(8)(10))
console.log(f(20)(22))
console.log(f(65)(65))
console.log(f(73)(73))
console.log(f(86)(84))
console.log(f(326)(318))
console.log(f(513)(518))

console.log('Falsy')
console.log(f(4)(5))
console.log(f(6)(8))
console.log(f(409)(401))
console.log(f(348)(347))
console.log(f(419)(418))
console.log(f(311)(313))
```

#### How?

```js
a => b =>                 // given a and b
  a == b |                // if a equals b, force success right away
  !(g = k =>              // g = recursive function taking k
    a % --k ?             //   decrement k; if k doesn't divide a:
      g(k)                //     recursive calls until it does
    :                     //   else:
      k < 2 ||            //     if k = 1: a is prime -> return true (failure)
      a - b &&            //     if a equals b: neither the original input integers nor
                          //     any integer between them are prime -> return 0 (success)
      g(a += a < b || -1) //     else: recursive call with a moving towards b
  )(a)                    // initial call to g()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> 46 bytes

*-17 by Giuseppe*

```r
function(a,b)!sd(range(numbers::isPrime(a:b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZBCoAgEADAe6@o2y5skIki0iP6gpaGBw00379Rp5nKcdxmjr0cT7oLOPI4tROqK1eA0rMPtVmb2l5TDuCsR0SOYEgsOERQQpIS5qumH7lqkotCfgE)

Pretty simple application of [ETHProductions' Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147258/72784). Main interesting takeaway <s>is</s> was that with R boolean vectors `any(x)==all(x)` is equivalent to `min(x)==max(x)`.

Comment: [this tip for golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12837/67312) is applicable here; and TIO [has `numbers` installed instead](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ0mzusI2rzQ3KbWo2MoqszigKDM3VSPRKkmTKzGvUqNC09Y2MScHSNf@T9Ow0DE00ORK0zA1NNYxNbQAMc10wJSxkZmOsYGp5n8A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, since `min(x)==max(x)` is equivalent to checking that all elements in `is_prime(a:b)` are equal, we can use [this last trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96916/67312) to get it down to [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcZBCoAgEADAe6@o2y5skIki0iP6gpaGBw00379Rp5nKcdxmjr0cT7oLOPI4tROqK1eA0rMPtVmb2l5TDuCsR0SOYEgsOERQQpIS5qumH7lqkotCfgE) with either the `primes` or the `numbers` package.

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, 28 bytes

```
v->s=Set(v);#s<2||!primes(s)
```

[Try it online with all test cases!](https://tio.run/##bc/BDsIgDAbgu0@B8QJJl1AKA6PzJTwaDx42s4OGjGWnvTvCxazGW/O19C/xMY3NM@ahy0tzSd21n@WiTod0Nuu6j9P46pNMKpfqPctB3gII1Heldl8xGoQxjFoHonWMPIHwxCi0IIJlRKYYYWDosLx1W9w0bWnx7LKUgdVHEFYjD7LlI2Q9n8Q6@ZNOiPUk@nOnrsn5Aw)

Returns `0` or `1` (usual PARI/GP "Boolean" values).

Explanation:

`v` must be a vector (or a column vector, or a list) with the two numbers `N` and `M` as coordinates. For example `[8, 10]`. Then `s` will be the "set" made from these numbers, which is either a one-coordinate vector (if `N==M`), or a two-coordinate vector with *sorted* entries otherwise.

Then if the number `#s` of coordinates in `s` is just one, we get `1` (truthy). Otherwise, `primes` will return a vector of all primes in the closed interval from `s[1]` to `s[2]`. Negation `!` of that will give `1` if the vector is empty, while negation of a vector of one or more non-zero entries (here one or more primes) will give `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆpżÆnE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW8HRPYfb8lz///8fbWxoqKNgbGgcCwA)

-2 thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18+16 = 34</s> 24 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
∧/=/4 ¯4∘.pco⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jvqnOkeopaXnF6lyPOpbr2@qbKBxab/KoY4ZeQXI@UBak7L8CGKRxWegoGBpwwXhGBjoKRkZwrpmpjoKZKZxrbqyjYG4M51qY6ShYmMC5xkZAvrGhBVzA1BCo3hRJwATIRZgN1IyQMbDUUTAxMEQYZgJ0mLGJOUKFIUgFkmHGhoYg64zR7DcwBQA)

Thanks to [Adám](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3073/adam) for 10 bytes.

The line `⎕CY'dfns'` (**C**OP**Y**) is needed to import the [*dfns*](http://dfns.dyalog.com/) (**d**ynamic **f**unctio**ns**) collection, included with default Dyalog APL installs.

#### How it works:

```apl
∧/=/4 ¯4∘.pco⎕ ⍝ Main function. This is a tradfn body.
             ⎕ ⍝ The 'quad' takes the input (in this case, 2 integers separated by a comma.
          pco  ⍝ The 'p-colon' function, based on p: in J. Used to work with primes.
    4 ¯4∘.     ⍝ Applies 4pco (first prime greater than) and ¯4pco (first prime smaller than) to each argument.
  =/           ⍝ Compares the two items on each row
∧/             ⍝ Applies the logical AND between the results.
               ⍝ This yields 1 iff the prime clusters are equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```python
lambda*v:v[0]==v[1]or{1}-{all(v%i for i in range(2,v))for v in range(min(v),max(v)+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzLasMwEEX38xWzKZZSBfTyowH/RXdpFiq1YoEsG8VWakK@3ZWhULo6w7n3zrTO/RjkZtuPzZvh88sc0imd@aVt01lcxvgQz@PDeE/Si0M7RnToAkYTrh2RLFG6u/TnBhdIomww3xmvgj63e@98h@9x6U6A6CxacnBhWmZC6W4Qp@jCjMUcl7lfi6w6f@v@Rdb421psDUPBQXKGUkJVMqxKqBXDWkFTMWw0KJmpRAOlyL7Mh86APQTN3xhqLkDp/EjpGrTYTS4pIfaZ@t3z8gc)

Comment: I like your set usage, even though it is [not required for 87 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzLCsIwEEX38xWzERLNIpNHW8X@hTt1EbHVQBtLqVG/vk5BcHWGc@@d4TPdH8nMbX2au9BfrmGdd/moz3Wdj3R@jBi6ToT0EXkV99SyiBgTjiHdGmFUlnJx@e/6mESWqg9vxoaknF/32DV4GJ/NDhCHMaYJW7GOaXhOgvNKIWkwWqExUHiFhYfSKiwtVIXCyoE1TEsVeGLv@XAMWEJweqvQaQLr@JF1JThaDJcs0TKzv732Xw).

Comment: @JonathanFrech I got it to 86 using sets

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>103 bytes</s> 100 bytes

```c
i,j,p,s;f(m,n){s=1;for(i=m>n?i=n,n=m,m=i:m;i<=n;i++,p?s=m==n:0)for(p=j=2;j<i;)p=i%j++?p:0;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBboMwEEXX4RQjpEggBsXGkFAcl10v0C6zSZPQGMWOhWFRRTk7NVGlSpXJ@v35@m8O6dfhMI4SWzRoeRMp1PHNCsqbaxdJoV51LYVGLRQqISvF5VZoLpMETW2FEkJXJJ6yRrQi4@1W8tgIuWyTpDYV4d2pHzoNlt9HqXtQe6mjOLgFi9UKPrqhP3@D2cvOBgsz9DYK38/X4XKEzxP0D1rtdJqmYcxdoHMNTRQujzsdIjRRiUBJ7EUZQcgyP1sXCOvCzzYMYcP8rFwjlLmfscxBRks/LairLX7pQ/1tf7H/zHf6z72Z8DP13PXN2LmRfpKTF4Sc0BmD3L2T5ZuZWzrdzvkxSid79uw35LH3Pv4A)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <strike>39</strike> <strike>27</strike> 26 bytes

```
Equal@@#~NextPrime~{-1,1}&
```

Expanded:

```
                         &  # pure function, takes 2-member list as input
       #~NextPrime~{-1,1}   # infix version of NextPrime[#,{-1,1}], which
                            # finds the upper and lower bounds of each
                              argument's prime clusters
Equal@@                     # are those bounds pairs equal?
```

Usage:

```
Equal@@#~NextPrime~{-1,1}& [{8, 10}]
(*  True  *)

Equal@@#~NextPrime~{-1,1}& [{6, 8}]
(*  False  *)

Equal@@#~NextPrime~{-1,1}& /@ {{8, 10}, {20, 22}, {65, 65}, 
    {73, 73}, {86, 84}, {326, 318}, {513, 518}}
(*  {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}  *)

Equal@@#~NextPrime~{-1,1}& /@ {{4, 5}, {6, 8}, {409, 401}, 
    {348, 347}, {419, 418}, {311, 313}}
(*  {False, False, False, False, False, False}  *)
```

Contributions: -12 bytes by [Jenny_mathy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67961/jenny-mathy), -1 byte by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)

Comment: This only checks next prime. Try NextPrime[#,{-1,1}]

Comment: @Jenny_mathy : I see you are correct.  Caught by the "348, 347" test case, which is now demonstrated to pass.

Comment: 27 bytes: `Equal@@NextPrime[#,{-1,1}]&` takes as input `[{N,M}]` or if you want to keep the original input use this 30 bytes: `Equal@@NextPrime[{##},{-1,1}]&`

Comment: @Jenny_mathy : Well, ..., the specified input is two integers, not a list, so ...

Comment: @EricTowers [taking a list is fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5439/8478). Also, you can save a byte by using infix notation `#~NextPrime~{-1,1}`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 81 bytes

A straightforward solution:

```hs
p z=[x|x<-z,all((0/=).mod x)[2..x-1]]!!0
c x=(p[x-1,x-2..],p[x+1..])
x!y=c x==c y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBa4MwFMbv@SueZYcEY5cYbR0sg10Kg@603USGdEpLrRWjLJb97@7F06bz8Mj3@957@dRjbs5FVY1jAzed2m/7GNx4XlWUinvN1pfrJ1iWhuu1DWSWeZ4gB7CaNilqbgM0Mo7Cl3hgxHqDdj6WYewK0xmdEsCHvrd9wYEmHKRgjP@BoeAQhnO6iTls4jndKg5bNafJhkMSzakKESuZzHkscUn8i@/yyjgjQryAbvWyUzxwiIRcGCrCV1TRdjkh3cQ/lyopXUq1NKb4AhNNPCOkBGo5DAw0WPBgIMR9Y8hrg1pD03dvXbuv4Q7M8fqFzPdhBQE8YcXjBGmJPxTVtPNUQulG9bSjOxY1dtLrma2gwBBO7J5f9mw1dZNLfqrxnkvevH4A7etD37YDuAxsqmb8AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
-:&(_4&p:,4&p:)
```

How it works:

```
   &(           ) - applies the verb in the brackets to both arguments
            4&p:  - The smallest prime larger than y
      _4&p:       - The largest prime smaller than y
           ,      - append
 -:               - matches the pairs of the primes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDsIgDIbve4rGw3DJNJQCmyS7@gTezWIkczFxGXrw4LMjDHbYgYavf/v/Hb110BngEJ4/mHJ/leVk6lgqXxW7IzDbGQY1/AxYVxT32/ACdpk/7@ELU/@YHUu9FiwgT3/BAwiRQKsAWiVoKEBDeUUHaGUCEpEI24QK46RakZ37p9sGyqjniOiTu/wUQHLMrjLeRbLJKi7q6kqISyZtTuDK/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
α╖ª»º√π├╔
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e0b7a6afa7fbe3c3c9&i=%5B8,+10%5D%0A%5B20,+22%5D%0A%5B65,+65%5D%0A%5B73,+73%5D%0A%5B86,+84%5D%0A%5B326,+318%5D%0A%5B513,+518%5D%0A%5B4,+5%5D%0A%5B6,+8%5D%0A%5B409,+401%5D%0A%5B348,+347%5D%0A%5B419,+418%5D%0A%5B311,+313%5D%0A%5B326,+305%5D&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŸpË
```

Port of [*@ETHproductions*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147258/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I6Cw93//0db6BgaxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NYwxCgJBDEWvsmz9i2SSzMRqDzJMoWBhpSAIewEbO09jL17Ei4yZBav3@LzkfN0fTsd@W5d5@t6f07ys/fO6vB8dvVYHU0NNhJSC2ZAtWARFgp7hGpSUIexhxgLbTDHKCIbTDko8SnWIlrFxbFspzHEt/z9krf0A).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ÿ    # Create an inclusive ranged list of the (implicit) input-pair
 p   # Check for each value in the list whether it's a prime (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
  Ë  # Check if all values are the same (so either all truthy or all falsey)
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```